# How do I delete from multiple tables using INNER JOIN in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In MySQL you can use the syntax

```
DELETE t1,t2 
FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ...
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ...
```

How do I do the same thing in SQL Server?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can take advantage of the "deleted" pseudo table in this example. Something like:

```
begin transaction;

   declare @deletedIds table ( id int );

   delete from t1
   output deleted.id into @deletedIds
   from table1 as t1
    inner join table2 as t2
      on t2.id = t1.id
    inner join table3 as t3
      on t3.id = t2.id;

   delete from t2
   from table2 as t2
    inner join @deletedIds as d
      on d.id = t2.id;

   delete from t3
   from table3 as t3 ...

commit transaction;
```

Obviously you can do an 'output deleted.' on the second delete as well, if you needed something to join on for the third table.

As a side note, you can also do inserted.* on an insert statement, and both inserted.* and deleted.* on an update statement.

**EDIT:**
Also, have you considered adding a trigger on table1 to delete from table2 + 3? You'll be inside of an implicit transaction, and will also have the "inserted.*" and "deleted.*" pseudo-tables available.

Comment: Is it better to just DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = x and then delete from next table instead of using inner join and going through all of this extra text?? Basically, skipping the inner join I just need 2 simple queries.... Or is this method any more efficient?

Comment: I think it depends on how complicated your where clause is. For a complicated one, this would be better because it only happens once. But for a simpler where clause that affects a lot of rows, your proposal would probably be more efficient since it doesn't have to hold many ids in a table variable.

Comment: @JohnGibb, How does this answer work? Can you explain this answer so that a MySQL dev can understand it?

Comment: @Pacerier I'm not very familiar with MySQL. The idea is that the first delete is only deleting from table1, but it's saving the IDs that were deleted into a variable. The subsequent two statements how uses that variable to delete the associated rows from table2 and table 3.

Comment: @JohnGibb, Now *that's* clear. You should include that in the answer.

Answer (score 16):

You can use JOIN syntax in FROM clause in DELETE in SQL Server but you still delete from first table only and it's proprietary Transact-SQL extension which is alternative to sub-query.

From example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx):

```
 -- Transact-SQL extension
 DELETE 
   FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory 
     FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory AS spqh INNER JOIN 
          Sales.SalesPerson AS sp ON spqh.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
    WHERE sp.SalesYTD > 2500000.00;
```

Comment: Example D: DELETE FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory 
FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory AS spqh
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS sp
ON spqh.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
WHERE sp.SalesYTD > 2500000.00;

Answer (score 15):

1. You can always set up cascading deletes on the relationships of the tables.
2. You can encapsulate the multiple deletes in one stored procedure.
3. You can use a transaction to ensure one unit of work.

Comment: Definitely possible to delete on a join statement, I just have want to delete from more than one table at a time.

Comment: Wrong answer, joins can be used with delete

Comment: ad 1.) That is not true, it might not always be possible. There are some scenarios where you cannot set up cascading deletes, e.g. cycles or multiple cascade paths. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3548225/108374 for example)

Answer (score 15):

Example for delete some records from master table and corresponding records from two detail tables:

```
BEGIN TRAN

  -- create temporary table for deleted IDs
  CREATE TABLE #DeleteIds (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  )

  -- save IDs of master table records (you want to delete) to temporary table    
  INSERT INTO #DeleteIds(Id)
  SELECT DISTINCT mt.MasterTableId
  FROM MasterTable mt 
  INNER JOIN ... 
  WHERE ...  

  -- delete from first detail table using join syntax
  DELETE d
  FROM DetailTable_1 D
  INNER JOIN #DeleteIds X
    ON D.MasterTableId = X.Id


  -- delete from second detail table using IN clause  
  DELETE FROM DetailTable_2
  WHERE MasterTableId IN (
    SELECT X.Id
    FROM #DeleteIds X
  )


  -- and finally delete from master table
  DELETE d
  FROM MasterTable D
  INNER JOIN #DeleteIds X
    ON D.MasterTableId = X.Id

  -- do not forget to drop the temp table
  DROP TABLE #DeleteIds

COMMIT
```

Comment: Could you use `SELECT INTO #DeleteIds` instead of `CREATE TABLE 'DeleteIds` followed by `INSERT INTO 'DeleteIds...`?

Answer (score 9):

Basically, no you have to make three delete statements in a transaction, children first and then parents. Setting up cascading deletes is a good idea if this is not a one-off thing and its existence won't conflict with any existing trigger setup.

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to do that, I suppose I'll have to select the ID's into a temp table since the relationship isn't a parent child one. once the rows from one table is gone there is no way to get the other rows.

Answer (score 9):

Just wondering.. is that really possible in MySQL?  it will delete t1 and t2? or I just misunderstood the question.

But if you just want to delete table1 with multiple join conditions, just don't alias the table you want to delete

this:

```
DELETE t1,t2 
FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ...
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ...
```

should be written like this to work in MSSQL:

```
DELETE table1
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ...
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ...
```

to contrast how the other two common RDBMS do a delete operation:

http://mssql-to-postgresql.blogspot.com/2007/12/deleting-duplicates-in-postgresql-ms.html

Comment: Thanks for the SQL Server tip there, I had to tweak the SQL along those lines.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL server there is no way to delete records from multiple tables using join.
So you have to delete from child first before delete form parent.

Comment: Something like this: DELETE ChildTable Where id=@id (new line) DELETE ParentTable Where id=@id?

(ids are PK and FK)

Answer (score 2):

All has been pointed out. Just use either `DELETE ON CASCADE` on the parent `table` or delete from the `child-table` and then `parent`.

Comment: What do you mean by delete from child table to the parent? do you mean by using joins technique like the one showed in question or aforementioned answers?

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative way of deleting records without leaving orphans.

```
Declare @user Table(keyValue int  , someString varchar(10))
insert into @user
values(1,'1 value')

insert into @user
values(2,'2 value')

insert into @user
values(3,'3 value')

Declare @password Table(  keyValue int , details varchar(10))
insert into @password
values(1,'1 Password')
insert into @password
values(2,'2 Password')
insert into @password
values(3,'3 Password')

        --before deletion
  select * from @password a inner join @user b
                on a.keyvalue = b.keyvalue
  select * into #deletedID from @user where keyvalue=1 -- this works like the output example
  delete  @user where keyvalue =1
  delete @password where keyvalue in (select keyvalue from #deletedid)

  --After deletion--
  select * from @password a inner join @user b
                on a.keyvalue = b.keyvalue
```

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron has already pointed out, you can set delete behaviour to CASCADE and that will delete children records when a parent record is deleted. Unless you want some sort of other magic to happen (in which case points 2, 3 of Aaron's reply would be useful), I don't see why would you need to delete with inner joins.

Answer (score 0):

To build upon John Gibb's answer, for deleting a set of data in two tables with a FK relationship:

```
--*** To delete from tblMain which JOINs to (has a FK of) tblReferredTo's PK  
--       i.e.  ON tblMain.Refer_FK = tblReferredTo.ID
--*** !!! If you're CERTAIN that no other rows anywhere also refer to the 
--      specific rows in tblReferredTo !!!
BEGIN TRAN;

    --*** Keep the ID's from tblReferredTo when we DELETE from tblMain
    DECLARE @tblDeletedRefs TABLE ( ID INT );
    --*** DELETE from the referring table first
    DELETE FROM tblMain 
    OUTPUT DELETED.Refer_FK INTO @tblDeletedRefs  -- doesn't matter that this isn't DISTINCT, the following DELETE still works.
    WHERE ..... -- be careful if filtering, what if other rows 
                --   in tblMain (or elsewhere) also point to the tblReferredTo rows?

    --*** Now we can remove the referred to rows, even though tblMain no longer refers to them.
    DELETE tblReferredTo
    FROM   tblReferredTo INNER JOIN @tblDeletedRefs Removed  
            ON tblReferredTo.ID = Removed.ID;

COMMIT TRAN;
```

Answer (score -4):

```
DELETE     TABLE1 LIN
FROM TABLE1 LIN
INNER JOIN TABLE2 LCS ON  CONDITION
WHERE CONDITION
```

Comment: it will not delete from two or more table.Please understand the question

Answer (score -5):

$sql="DELETE FROM `basic_tbl`,`education_tbl`,
`personal_tbl` ,`address_tbl`,`department_tbl`
USING 
`basic_tbl`,`education_tbl`,
`personal_tbl` ,`address_tbl`,`department_tbl` 
WHERE 
`b_id`=`e_id`=`p_id`=`a_id`=`d_id`='".$id."'
";
 $rs=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

Comment: Please fix your formatting and provide a brief description of why your code works.