# Entity Framework 4.1 InverseProperty Attribute and ForeignKey

Tags: c#, mapping, entity, entity-framework-4.1, cascading-deletes

I will create two references between Employee and Team entities with foreign keys.
So I defined two entities as follow

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FirstTeam")]
    public int FirstTeamId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("FirstEmployees")]
    public virtual Team FirstTeam { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SecondTeam")]
    public int SecondTeamId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("SecondEmployees")]
    public virtual Team SecondTeam { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("FirstTeam")]
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> FirstEmployees { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("SecondTeam")]
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> SecondEmployees { get; set; }
}
```

I thought it is correct theoretically, but it shows the Exception as follow :

```
{"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'Employee_SecondTeam' on table 'Employees' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.\r\nCould not create constraint. See previous errors."}
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance
Kwon

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is theoretically correct but SQL server (not Entity framework) doesn't like it because your model allows single employee to be a member of both First and Second team. If the `Team` is deleted this will cause multiple delete paths to the same `Employee` entity.

This cannot be used together with cascade deletes which are used by default in EF code first if you define foreign key as mandatory (not nullable).

If you want to avoid the exception you must use fluent mapping:

```
public Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                    .HasRequired(e => e.SecondTeam)
                    .WithMany(t => t.SecondEmployees)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.FirstTeamId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        ...
    }
}
```

This will result in scenario where you must delete members of SecondTeam manually before you delete the team.

Comment: But if you let EF to generate keys it will make them nullable (optional relation). When using fluent mapping it will also use name of the column as foreign key.

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comments. However, if so, should it be possible if I define the foreign key property as nullable like public int? FirstTeamId {get; set;} ?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka is there an attribute instead of fluent?

Comment: @Shimmy yes, [Required] on child nav. property

Comment: I found I had to use  modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();  to get a similar thing working

Comment: +1 for this sentence "...cascade deletes which are used by default ...foreign key as mandatory..." I would upvote this 1k times...

Answer (score 2):

All is correct in previous answer, but one thing is wrong

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.SecondTeam)
                .WithMany(t => t.SecondEmployees)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.SecondTeamId) // mistake
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

`FirstTeamId` instead of `SecondTeamId` will cause that in `SecondTeam navigation` property will be always `FirstTeam`