# How should I model friendships between users with EF code first?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm tring to figure out how to represent friendships between users with Entity Framework (5) Code First. My initial idea was to create a class Friendship which contains references to two User instances, so that friendships are represented by separate objects.

```
public class Friendship
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual UserProfile User1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual UserProfile User2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime Since { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to create the database via EF Migrations, however, I'm stumped due to a SQL error:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Friendships_dbo.UserProfile_User2_UserId' on table 'Friendships' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

Suggestions as to how to solve this problem would be very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find a similar question on SO after some more googling, and there's a solution there that at least made it into the database without problems.

Basically, I added foreign keys per user to the `Friendship` class, made them a composite primary key and configured the second foreign key not to cascade on delete. I ended up using EF fluent configuration.

```
public class Friendship
{
    public virtual int UserId1 { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserId2 { get; set; }
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; }
    public virtual User User2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime since;
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>().HasKey(f => new { f.UserId1, f.UserId2 });
    modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
      .HasRequired(f => f.User1)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId1);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
        .HasRequired(f => f.User2)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId2)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the foreign keys yourself or remove cascade delete, depending on your scenario. See this related question : [Entity Framework Code First: FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216711/entity-framework-code-first-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple)