# Code First one to many relationship and category with parent category

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> ParentCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ImageSet> ImageSets { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentCategoryId")]
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
}    

public class ImageSet
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageSetId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string InsertDate { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public int ImageSetId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string ThumbImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string InsertDate { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ImageSetId")]
    public virtual ImageSet ImageSet { get; set; }
}

Context:
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ImageSet> ImageSets { get; set; }
```

> *error page:Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ImageSets_dbo.Categories_CategoryId' on table 'ImageSets' may
>   cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could
>   not create constraint. See previous errors.*

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ImageSet>()
.HasRequired(is => is.Category)
.WithMany(c => c.ImageSets)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Here are good explanations of why this is happening :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19390016/1845408

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17127512/1845408

Comment: Eyvallah hocam, Allah razı olsun... Şu mecraya da Türkçe serpiştirelim biraz. :D