# FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths [error message]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I add `provincesModel`'s `pr_id` as a `foreign Key` to `clinicsModel`. So the visual studio display me this error message

`Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ClinicsModels_dbo.ProvincesModels_pr_id' on table 'ClinicsModels' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.`

I try to solve the issue by browsing on web to find some solution but I can't get how to solve this. So I remove the `foreign key` relation of `pr_id` from `clinicsModel` and run the project but still visual studio shows me the same error message. I also recreate the `ClinicsModel` and try to update database using `Update-Database -Verebose Migrations` using `package manager console` but still it shows the same error message.

Here's my code:

for `ProvinceModel`

```
namespace finalFyp.Models
{
    public class ProvincesModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int pr_id { get; set; }
        public string pr_name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CitiesModel> cities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`ClinicsModel`:

```
 public class ClinicsModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int clinic_id { get; set; }
        public string clinic_name { get; set; }
        public string clinic_address { get; set; }
        //Forigen Keys
        public int ct_id { get; set; }
        public CitiesModel city { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As the error occurred when I redirecting to `http://localhost:3110/Doctors/index`
Here's the snapshot of of error message.
[image]

`DoctorsModel`:

```
public class DoctorsModel
{
    [Key]
    public int d_id { get; set; }
    public string d_name { get; set; }
    public string contact { get; set; }
    public string cnic { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    //Forigen Key
    public ICollection<DocExperiencesModel> experiences { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DocSpecialization> specializations { get; set; }
    public ICollection<QualificationsModel> qualifications { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DoctorProfileModel> profiles { get; set; }
}
```

For ease of understanding Here's the schema of my database.
[image]

Please guide me what I suppose to do? I will be very thankful to him/her.

Answer (score 0):

From first glance, the error occured when `pr_id` added as foreign key to `ClinicsModel` because `ProvincesModel` has one-to-many relationship against `ClinicsModel` table which involves `pr_id` primary key field. Since all foreign keys which referencing `pr_id` are not nullable, all one-to-many relationships where `ProvincesModel` involved are having cascade delete enabled by default. Hence, it means when a `ClinicsModel` entity data is deleted, it will have 2 cascade delete paths: through `CitiesModel` and directly to `ProvincesModel` as shown in image below.

[image: Multiple Cascade Delete]

As a result, it establishing circular relationship with more than one cascade delete path from `ClinicsModel` to `ProvincesModel` which causes error 1785 in SQL Server.

To resolve relationships problem, `pr_id` foreign keys should declared as `Nullable<int>`:

```
public int? pr_id { get; set; }
```

Likewise, if `ct_id` (and other `int` foreign key properties which subjected to possible circular relationships) also returning same error, declare them with same way as above:

```
public int? ct_id { get; set; }
```

**NB:** If Fluent API (and Code First) is being used, try adding these lines below:

```
// taken from /a/20915232
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
}

// modified from /a/17127512
// used on all entities with circular relationships
var builder = new DbModelBuilder();
builder.Entity<CitiesModel>()
       .HasRequired(x => x.ct_id)
       .WithMany()
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

builder.Entity<ProvincesModel>()
       .HasRequired(x => x.pr_id)
       .WithMany()
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Similar issues:

[Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

[Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373310/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

[Error message 1785 occurs when you create a FOREIGN KEY constraint that may cause multiple cascade paths](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321843/error-message-1785-occurs-when-you-create-a-foreign-key-constraint-that-may-cause-multiple-cascade-paths)