# Entity Framework - Error with cascade

Tags: c#, entity-framework, cascade

I have a problem using Entity Framework and the cascade option. I'm using code first.
I have a product table and a config table.

The config has the columns: Id, Value, Language, Entity Framework has added 2 extra colums called product_id, product_id1, because a product has 2 config properties. When I use the following code:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductEntity>().HasMany(e => e.Config1).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductEntity>().HasMany(e => e.Config2).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

I get the error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Configs_dbo.ProductEntities_ProductEntity_Identifier1' on table 'Configs' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

When I only do config1 everything works and 1 of the 2 entries in the database will be removed. Does anyone know how I can make sure that also the second entry will be removed?

Comment: Need to see the models and nav properties. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373310/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Comment: My code smell detector is going nuts...