# Prevent CASCADE DELETE that causes "cycles or multiple cascade paths"

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a relationship like

```
public class Widget
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetPair
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Widget WidgetA { get; set; }
    public virtual int WidgetAId { get; set; }

    public virtual Widget WidgetB { get; set; }
    public virtual int WidgetBId { get; set; }
}
```

Note that Widget has no concept of a WidgetPair in the object model.

When I try to update my database with EF Code First migrations, I get the error

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.WidgetPairs_dbo.Widget_WidgetAId' on table 'WidgetPairs' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Makes sense, because SQL Server does not like [two properties from the table pointing to the same parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224933/141172).

The desired behavior is that, if a given WidgetPair.WidgetA (or .WidgetB) points to a particular Widget that is subsequently deleted, that WidgetA (or WidgetB) becomes null.

I do not want a delete in either the Widget table or the WidgetPairs table to delete a row in the other table.

It seems like I can configure this using the fluent interface, but I cannot see exactly how to do that.  If I wanted to add a reference from Widget to WidgetPair (which I do *not*), the following seems like it would work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<WidgetPair>().HasOptional(p => p.WidgetA)
  .WithMany(q => q.TheChildWidget)
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This will not work because a single Widget could participate in many WidgetPairs.  Also, there is no domain requirement for a Widget to directly know what WidgetPairs it participates in.

Is it possible to configure this behavior?  How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I made the relationship from WidgetPair to Widget non-nullable by using the type *int* for the foreign key.  That in turn causes the cascade delete.

Changing the type to *int?* resolves the issue:

```
public virtual Widget WidgetA { get; set; }
public virtual int? WidgetAId { get; set; }
```