# EF Code First giving problems in foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

```
public class ParikshaContext :DbContext
{
    public ParikshaContext()
    {

       Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ParikshaContext>());

    }
    public DbSet<UserDetail> UserDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuestionDescriptor> QuestionDescriptors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuestionBrief> QuestionBriefs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuestionCustom> QuestionCustoms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuestionChoice> QuestionChoices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuestionMatch> QuestionMatches { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Test_Question> Test_Questions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionCustom>().ToTable("Custom");
        modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionBrief>().ToTable("Brief");
        modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionMatch>().ToTable("Match");
        modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionChoice>().ToTable("Choice");
    }       
} 

public class QuestionDescriptor
{

    public int QuestionDescriptorId { get; set; } 

    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StandardId")]
    public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }

    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubjectId")]
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public int Difficulty { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfCreation{get;set;}

    public int UserDetailId { get; set; }     
    [ForeignKeyAttribute("UserDetailId")]
    public virtual UserDetail Creator { get; set; }

}

public class QuestionBrief : QuestionDescriptor
{
    public String QuestionText { get; set; }
    public String Answer { get; set; }
    //true for fill in the blanks and false for a loing answers
    public bool Short { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public String StandardName { get; set; }

}

public class Subject
{
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public String SubjectName { get; set; }
    public String SubjectCategory { get; set; }        

  //  public int StandardId { get; set; }
  //  [ForeignKey("StandardId")]
   // public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{

    public int TestID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfCreation { get; set; }    

    public String StandardName { get; set; }
    public String SubjectName { get; set; }
    public String SubjectCategory { get; set; }

//    public int UserDetailId { get; set; }
//    [ForeignKey("UserDetailId")]
 //   public virtual UserDetail Creator { get; set; }


}

public class Test_Question
{

    public int Test_QuestionID { get; set; }     

    public int TestId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TestId")]
    public virtual Test Test { get; set; }

    public int QuestionDescriptorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("QuestionDescriptorId")]
    public virtual QuestionDescriptor Question { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetail
{

    public int UserDetailId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "UserName must be 10 characters or less"), MinLength(5)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public String UserRole { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfCreation{  get; set;}    
}

//Match,Custom,Choice classes have been omitted for lack of space (which sounds stupid when i look at the amount of code i have pasted )
```

I have two problems:-

1. I cant get a foreign key relation between standard and subjects,it says the relation will cause several cascade delete paths...
2. if I make a foreign key rlation between test and usedetail it gives me the above problem for mapping  the tst_question table .

Also since I am new to EF code first ,please point out my mistakes.all help and disccussion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default EF will create foreign keys will `cascade delete`. In your model if you delete a `Standard` there are multiple paths to delete the `QuestionDescriptor`.

> Standard -> QuestionDescriptor

and

> Standard -> Subject -> QuestionDescriptor

That is why SQL server does not allow you to do this. See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreignkey-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths/852047#852047)

What you can do is explicitly tell EF to create foreign keys without `cascade delete`. **But this may create data integrity problems. So make sure you understand the consequences.**

What you can do is configure the relationships using fluent API with `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  //other mappings

      modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>()
        .HasRequired(subject => subject.Standard).WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(subject => subject.StandardId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help.I want the foreign key between standard and subject to cascade as well,since the subject is dependent upon the standard.Can i not have multiple paths ,because i don't see any cycles there ?

Comment: @ashutosh then configure `Standard -> QuestionDescriptor` without cascade. You may need to add a trigger to do the deletion. experiment what works right for you.

Comment: yup...i agree with you . do u think it is better if i keep all of my mapping logic separate and use fluent api rather than annotations?

Comment: @ashutosh there are pros and cons in both approaches. attribute based configurations is very limited. I would use fluent API for mappings.