# ef two relations

Tags: ef-code-first, associations, entity-framework-5

I have the following Entity Framework 5 code first classes

```
public class Airplane
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int LeftWingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Wing LeftWing { get; set; }

    public int RightWingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Wing RightWing { get; set; }
}

public class Wing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Airplane has one left and one right wing (both are required). Wing may belong to a 0..1 airplane (as a left or right wing) or to some other "flying device".
Deleting an airplane should cascade-delete it's wings.

How can this be configured in code-first fluent API?

Is it possible to have two 0..1 --- 1 associations in EF with cascade delete on both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot have two associations pointing from same source table to same target table with cascade delete on both.

However, that is not due to limitation in EF, but in SQL server.

Quote from [answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/852047/408643) you might want to check:

> SQL Server does simple counting of cascade paths and, rather than
>   trying to work out whether any cycles actually exist, it assumes the
>   worst and refuses to create the referential actions (CASCADE): you can
>   and should still create the constraints without the referential
>   actions. If you can't alter your design (or doing so would compromise
>   things) then you should consider using triggers as a last resort.