# Modeling an N-level tree in SQL Server with cascading deletes

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-key-relationship, cascading-deletes, self-referencing-table

I need to model an n-level tree in SQL Server.  I originally did something like this to create a `Node` table:

```
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ParentId] [bigint] NULL
```

It's a self referential table, where `ParentID` refers back to another `Node` entity (the root has a `null` `ParentID`).
But when I try to add a constraint to cascade deletes, I get this:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Nodes_dbo.Nodes_ParentId' on table 'Nodes' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

From what I read, this seems to be a pretty well known, and reasonable limitation in SQL Server.  Some people suggest using a trigger to accomplish this, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

So my question is - how should an n-level hierarchy or tree be modelled in SQL in order to allow cascading deletes?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths

Comment: ps. Are you able to use stored procedures to perform the delete operations?  i.e. rather than putting this logic in a constraint / trigger and having those handle the recursive deletion of parents when a delete takes place, put all this logic into a stored proc and call that for any deletes.  That won't help if people can access the database directly, but most of the time I'd assume people will be going through a front end program, so you can point it to the proc rather than writing a delete statement.

Comment: @JohnLBevan, That's essentially what I ended up doing.  I'm using EntityFramework, so I just used the Repository Pattern, and made the repository's delete function recursive.  I don't care about efficiency with this app, but if I did, I'd probably move the logic to a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

One of the more effective techniques I've seen for doing this is to make the clustered primary key be the **variable length full tree path** of the node ([hat tip to Richard Henderson](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TreeInSql)); to delete a subtree, one need then only delete a range of values.