# Constraint between tables in SQL Server, deleting one should delete the other

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating two tables RegistrationHeader and RegistrationDetail. How can i add a constraint that when i delete RegistrationHeader table to automaicaly delete the RegistrationDetail table.

```
create table RegistrationHeader(
    RegistrationNo numeric
    ,BillingID varchar(30) not null
    ,RegistrationDate date not null
    ,PaymentType varchar check (PaymentType = 'CC' or PaymentType = 'PO' or PaymentType = 'Check') not null
    ,CCNumber numeric check(CCNumber >= 15 and CCNumber <=16)
    ,PONumber varchar(30)
    ,CheckNumber varchar(10)
    ,primary key(RegistrationNo)
    ,foreign key(BillingId) references Person(UserID) 
    ,constraint CC_CCNumber_constr check(
        (PaymentType = 'CC' and CCNumber is not null)
        or
        (PaymentType != 'CC' and CCNumber is null)
    )
    ,constraint PO_PONumber_constr check(
        (PaymentType = 'PO' and (PONumber is not null or PONumber != ''))
        or
        (PaymentType != 'PO' and PONumber is null)
    )
    ,constraint CheckNumber_type_constr check(PaymentType != 'Check' and CheckNumber is null)
);

create table RegistrationDetail(
    RegistrationNo numeric
    ,LineNumber numeric
    ,CourseID numeric(10) not null
    ,AttendeeID varchar(30) not null
    primary key(RegistrationNo,LineNumber)
);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: SQL Server, MySQL, etc...?

Comment: In the header i mentioned sql, I will capitalize it. Thanks

Comment: Right.  There is more than one type of SQL DBMS.

Comment: **SQL** is just the **query language** - but **not** a database product....

Comment: Sorry, I have adjusted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to

1) Set up foreign key relations between `RegistrationHeader.RegistrationNo` and `RegistrationDetail.RegistrationNo`

2) Add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to RegistrationDetail Foreign Key definition

I haven't tested this, but I believe this should be what you're looking for in **SQL Server**

```
ALTER TABLE RegistrationDetail
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RegistrationHeader_RegistrationDetail_Cascade
FOREIGN KEY (RegistrationNo) REFERENCES RegistrationDetail (RegistrationNo) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: If i do this i get: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_RegistrationHeader_RegistrationDetail_Cascade' on table 'RegistrationDetail' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths).  You may need to create triggers if you're not able to modify your constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Constrains are affecting only database columns such as primary/foreign keys or regular columns, not whole tables. You can add `OnDelete` or `OnUpdate` constraints for foreign keys to delete/keep the refrences from one table to other but not the whole table. That is mixing `DML`(select,update,insert,delete) with `DDL`(create,drop). Try to read more about `DML` and `DDL`.

[Here's](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_are_the_difference_between_ddl_dml_and_dcl_commands)
a good article about that