# SQL Server 2012: Database can't delete a record

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

I have two tables `BillOfMaterials` and `Product` in `AdventureWorks2012` database. What am I gonna do is try to `Modify` in `BillOfMaterials`->`FK_BillOfMaterials_Product_ProductAssemblyID`like a picture below:

[image]

But it got a problem:

```
'Product (Production)' table saved successfully
'BillOfMaterials (Production)' table
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_BillOfMaterials_Product_ProductAssemblyID'.  
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_BillOfMaterials_Product_ProductAssemblyID' on table 'BillOfMaterials' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Is there any solution for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths

Comment: If you were able to fix it, please post your solution as an answer.