# Issue with multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

I have designed an diagram in sql server 2008.
as you can see in the photo:

[image]

Now in `Value` table I set the cascading delete ON for `Feature` and `ProductDetail` but I see the error below:

> 'Feature' table saved successfully 'ProductDetail' table saved
>   successfully 'Value' table
>   - Unable to create relationship 'ValueFeature'.   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'ValueFeature' on table 'Value' may cause cycles or
>   multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO
>   ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create
>   constraint. See previous errors.

What is it wrong with my design?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreign key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have faced the same problem some years ago, in SQL server 2005. I suppose that **nothing is wrong with your design**. If you delete a `Feature` you want all the `Value` records to be deleted. Nothing wrong with that. If you don't have other cascades, the automatic delete will not propagate further. However, it seems that **SQL Server is not clever enough to understand that**, and does not allow you to have such a relationship, just because you have foreign keys that form a circle. I think that if you remove a foreign key (just for testing) and break the circle (for example delete the FK between the `ProductDetail` and `Product`) there would be no error.

Check [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths) too..

Hope I helped!