# SQL Server Relation table parent->child and cycle cascade

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a sql table (let's call it Person) like, for example :

TABLE Person

```
Id  Firstname  Lastname
```

I want to make relations beetwen somme of this person (parent/child relation) so I built another table (let's call it Person_Relation) like that :

TABLE Person_Relation

```
Id_person_parent   Id_person_child
```

I made a constraint to avoid the case where parent = child (it would be awkward !) and now i try to make foreign key beetwen table Person and table Person_Relation.I am currently able to make one foreign key, but when i try to set the second I get a : **may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths** error.

Knowing that I would keep the **'Delete cascade'** to automatically delete links in Person_Relation table when an entry in Person is deleted, is there any clean solution to do that ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server won't let you create multiple cascade paths that could theoretically conflict. For more on that, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths).

One way to still achieve your goal is to use a trigger in place of a foreign key with a cascade action.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Person_Delete
ON dbo.Person
FOR DELETE
AS
  DELETE dbo.Person_Relation 
  WHERE Id_person_parent IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)
    OR Id_person_child IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted);
```