# Sql table shared for multiple 1-many relationships with delete cascade

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a table that can be in a 1-* relationship with one of 2 different tables. I currently have it setup where there are 2 nullable columns that reference another table. However, this is causing an issue for cascade deletions.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TA] (
    [Id]               INT                IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB] (
    [Id]               INT                IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TAId]             INT                NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TB_To_TA] FOREIGN KEY ([TAId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TA] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TC] (
    [Id]               INT                IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TAId]             INT                NULL,
    [TBId]             INT                NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TC] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TC_To_TA] FOREIGN KEY ([TAId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TA] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TC_To_TB] FOREIGN KEY ([TBId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TB] ([Id]), -- NOTE: DELETE CASCADE CAUSES A CIRCULAR REFERENCE
);
```

Essentially, this creates a nested structure like:

```
TA1
 + -- TC1, TC2
 + -- TB1
       + -- TC3, TC4
```

A TC object should only be a child of either TA or TB (not both). How should I go about developing this so that I can DELETE a TA row and have all TC and TB referenced rows deleted as well?

Comment: The problem with this is that based on the structure of TC it can be the child of TA, TB, both, or none. I cannot think of a way to accomplish this. This was an answer to a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths

Comment: That's unfortunate... I guess I could remove [TC] and instead create [TBC] and [TAC] tables where [TBC] and [TAC] are identical except for the [TBId] and [TAId] FK columns, but that seems so repetitive...

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this I ended up breaking [TC] into multiple tables as [described in a blog for entity framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines). This created the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TA] (
    [Id]               INT                IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB] (
    [Id]               INT                IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TAId]             INT                NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TB_To_TA] FOREIGN KEY ([TAId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TA] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TCA] (
    [Id]               INT                IDENTITY (2, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TAId]             INT                NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TCA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TCA_To_TA] FOREIGN KEY ([TAId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TA] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TCB] (
    [Id]               INT                IDENTITY (1, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TBId]             INT                NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TCB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TCB_To_TB] FOREIGN KEY ([TBId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TB] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
```

I set the identities to even\odd values in order to prevent collision when creating a union of the two tables (see above link).