# SQL Server - Foreign Key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql-server

Here's my database for a notification system (it has been stripped down for simplicity). When the a User is deleted I want the related Notification and UserEmail to be deleted but I get the constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths error when I try to set the relationship to ON DELETE Cascade.

```
Unable to create relationship 'FK_Notification_TargetUser'.  
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Notification_TargetUser' on table 'Notification' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

[image: database diagram]

After doing some research my possible solutions are:

- Add an Instead Of Delete trigger to the User table and manually delete the child tables.
- Redesign the tables as suggested here:
  [Foreign key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths) However I'm not quite sure what it would like in my case.
- Do a logical/soft delete. (recommended in the comments)

Any recommendations for what I should do?

Additional Resources:

- [Implementing Referential Integrity and Cascading Actions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902684(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: Delete rows manually from dedicated stored procedure or application, what is the problem? Is cascading an universal panacea?

Comment: don't you want to cascade from user to notifications?  this does not make sense to me, why should deleting a notification cause a user to be deleted.

Comment: @Hogan : Yes that's what I meant. Sorry that it wasn't clear.

Comment: you don't have to be clear to me... just to sql-server.

Comment: I'd go with the trigger.     ...at least out of the two choices you're considering.   I'd actually go with a soft-delete model if it were solely up to me.

Comment: Just for the record I think soft-delete model is better.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks for the recommendation. I guess another bonus of using that approach is that I would get a history of notifications.