# Cascade on delete using EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm developing an Entity Framework Code First 6.1.3 library with C# and .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I have these three tables:
[image]

And these there `EntityTypeConfiguration` files:
Class `CHILDSConfiguration`:

```
class AGGREGATION_CHILDSConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AGGREGATION_CHILDS>
{
    public AGGREGATION_CHILDSConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.CHILD_CODE);

        Property(ag_ch => ag_ch.CHILD_CODE)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(ag_ch => ag_ch.CHILD_CODE)
            .HasMaxLength(20)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("CODE");

        Property(ag_ch => ag_ch.PARENT_CODE)
            .HasMaxLength(20)
            .IsRequired();

        HasRequired(ag_ch => ag_ch.Aggregation)
            .WithMany(ag => ag.AggregationChilds)
            .HasForeignKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.PARENT_CODE);

        HasRequired(ag_ch => ag_ch.Code)
            .WithOptional(c => c.AggregationChild)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Class `AGGREGATIONSConfiguration`:

```
class AGGREGATIONSConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AGGREGATIONS>
{
    public AGGREGATIONSConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(ag => ag.PARENT_CODE);

        Property(ag => ag.PARENT_CODE)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(ag => ag.PARENT_CODE)
            .HasMaxLength(20)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("CODE");

        Property(ag => ag.CREATED)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsOptional();

        HasRequired(ag => ag.Code)
            .WithOptional(c => c.Aggregation)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Class `CODESConfiguration`:

```
class CODESConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CODES>
{
    public CODESConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(c => c.CODE);

        Property(c => c.CODE)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(c => c.CODE)
            .HasMaxLength(20);

        Property(c => c.CODE_LEVEL)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(c => c.COMMISIONING_FLAG)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(c => c.IS_TRANSMITTED)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(c => c.TIMESPAN)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsOptional();

        Property(c => c.USERNAME)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsOptional();

        Property(c => c.SOURCE)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsOptional();

        Property(c => c.REASON)
            .HasMaxLength(200)
            .IsOptional();

        Property(c => c.ALTERNATE_CODE)
            .IsOptional();

        Property(c => c.HELPER_CODE)
            .IsOptional();
    }
}
```

I want to do this: if I delete a row on `CODES` table, I want to delete that code on `AGGREGATIONS` and on `AGGREGATION_CHILDS` table.

How can I do that using Entity Framework Code First?

I've had to add `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);` because I get an error about cycles and multiple cascade routes.

Answer (score 1):

That error almost saw my laptop through the window a few times... basically the reason why it's not working is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)... But the good news is, we can fix this by removing a relationship which is already implicitly defined.

This relationship is the one you can remove completely:

```
AggregationsChild > HasRequired > Code
```

The reason is that `Aggregation` has a `One to Many` relationship with `AggregationChild`

```
Aggregation > HasMany > AggregationChild
```

`Aggregation` also has a dependency on `Code`

```
Aggregation > HasRequired > Code
```

Now since `AggregationChild` is a child of `Aggregation`, and `Aggregation` is a child of `Code`. The extra dependency from `AggregationChild` to `Code` is creating multiple cascade paths, so remove it entirely, and that should fix your issues...

To find out which `Code` the `AggregationChild` is part of, you'll first need to get the parent of `AggregationChild` and then navigate to the `Code` entity via `Aggregation`....

```
var aggregationChild = this.AggregationChildren.Include("Aggregation.Code")
                                               .First(ac => ac.Id == 123);
var code = aggregationChild.Aggregation.Code;
```