# SQLServer two foreign keys pointing to same column

Tags: sql-server

I have this concept code *(with some comments)*:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'test')
SET NOEXEC ON
GO

-- didn't use EXEC sp_executesql for Syntax Highlighting and Code Compeltion in MSSMS
CREATE SCHEMA [test]
GO

SET NOEXEC OFF
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- child is a list
CREATE TABLE [test].[Child] (
    [ChildId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Child] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ChildId]) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
)

-- parent is a tree
CREATE TABLE [test].[Parent] (
    [ParentId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [ParentPid] BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY([ParentPid]) REFERENCES [test].[Parent] ([ParentId]),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Parent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ParentId]) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
)

-- each child can have any number of parents
CREATE TABLE [test].[ChildParent] (
    [ChildId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY([ChildId]) REFERENCES [test].[Child] ([ChildId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    [ParentId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY([ParentId]) REFERENCES [test].[Parent] ([ParentId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ChildParent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ChildId], [ParentId]) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
)

-- () This table is internal and used readonly, generated by a trigger on ChildParent
-- that creates associations between each Child & Parent + all the Parent's Parents
-- this way flatteting the Parent structure and making deep querying easier.
-- () ChildId + ParentPid point directly to the original Child + Parent relationship
-- that when it's deleted, it automatically deletes all the Child + Parent's Parents.
-- () I also need the table to automagically delete any row when any Child/Parent's gone.
CREATE TABLE [test].[Parent_Child] (
    [ParentId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY([ParentId]) REFERENCES [test].[Parent] ([ParentId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    [ChildId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY([ChildId]) REFERENCES [test].[Child] ([ChildId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    [ParentPid] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY([ParentPid]) REFERENCES [test].[Parent] ([ParentId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY([ChildId], [ParentPid]) REFERENCES [test].[ChildParent] ([ChildId], [ParentId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Parent_Child] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ParentId], [ChildId], [ParentPid]) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

The last table won't create and [I know why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths), even if I don't agree with it at all as I can't see how this exact scenario can break anything or make anything difficult for SQLServer. MySQL does *(or at least did 1yr ago when I last used it)* this without a problem.

I also know that any change I make *(drop DELETE CASCADE, drop FOREIGN KEYS all together)* in the above *(illegal SQL)* will force me to do cleanup on client side `(C#)` and break my neatly designed database.

> Considering I'd like to keep all `Parent_Child` maintenance SQLServer-side so the C# client just reads it, is there any workaround for this situation?

***PS:*** Thought of using a `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger but doc says you can't use it on tables with `FOREIGN KEY DELETE CASCADE`.

**ERROR:** *may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.*.

Comment: so.. what error do you get?

Comment: One workaround is to only make change through a stored procedure and embed required logic in there.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Added it in the footer of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a workaround to the situation while not doing any work client-side:

- Created a new table where I flatten the entire Parent hierarchy with a Trigger on `Parent`.
- Use this new table for queries being only a join away from my original design but not being recursive.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [test].[ParentTree]
(
    [ParentId] BIGINT NOT NULL, -- no fkey, but I double the value on column 2 so no need
    [ParentPid] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY([ParentPid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Parent] ([ParentId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ParentTree] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ParentId], [ParentPid]) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
)
GO
```

So the flat hierarchy is achieved with a trigger on `Parent`, a recursive `CTE` function and an `OUTER APPLY` to use the function against the `Parents`. If I have a `'z'` child of `'y'` child of `'x'`, then my flat table contains:

```
[Child] [Parent]
x x -- notice child is parent of child
y y -- notice child is parent of child
y x
z z -- notice child is parent of child
z y
z x
```

This allows me to do the deep queries on a flat data set. And I can also have `DELETE CASCADE` on column 2 as I double the child value so I can avoid no double fkeys.

To query all `[Child]` in `[Parent]` `X` *(including those in child `Y` and `Z` of `X`)* I just do:

```
DECLARE @ParentId BIGINT = 0
SELECT DISTINCT [ChildId]
FROM [test].[ChildParent] [t1]
    JOIN [test].[ParentTree] [t2]
        ON ([t2].[ParentId] = [t1].[ParentId] AND [t2].[ParentPid] = @ParentId)
GO
```

I might even reduce the complexity further but this is my workaround for the fkey cascade mess.

**PS**: *Duplicating a fkey (so I can have just one) might have also worked on the original design but I'm OK with this solution so I won't try to change the original code to work like this.*