# Why is on delete cascade impossible for nullable columns?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, ssms, nullable

I was trying to `create` a `table` via SSMS 11.0.6020.0 using SQL Server, via the `table` designer. I have defined the `primary key`, the `column`s and `foreign key`s. All was well, but when I have hit Ctrl+s to save the script, I received an error message stating that `On Delete Cascade` may cause cycles and change the remove behavior. I have followed the instructions given and changed the `on delete` and `on update` to `do nothing` for the `nullable` `column` used as `foreign key`, but I wonder what is the problem with `on delete cascade` and `on update cascade` for `nullable` `foreign key`.

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths), but as far as I know it is not a duplicate, since I have a single reference to a given `table` and the problem was that it was `nullable` and the other question is about multiple references. The error message is similar though.

I believe that if that `column` is `null` for a record, then it does not have a reference in the referenced `table`, therefore there is no reference which could trigger `delete`/`update` on that record. However, if there is a reference, that could act as if the `column` was not `nullable` in that case. Is there an objective reason for this behavior (like performance, indexing, etc.)? I can simply not see the possible cycles when a `nullable` `column` is used as a `foreign key`, as the `null` values should be immune to changes at the reference table according to my opinion.

Comment: Why on earth would you ever use cascade delete to begin with?

Comment: I would like to make sure that whenever a referenced record is removed, the record having a foreign key pointing to that record is removed as well.

Comment: But cascade delete is a very poor practice. If you ended up with 10,000,000 child records it could cause a huge lock up of your system.   It is not permitted by many dbas for this reason.

Comment: I understand your point and it is valid in many cases, but I am not so strict about this specific issue, I think about my schema and the nature of the data I will store along with potential problems. I am not worried about huge system locks regarding this specific data.