# Laravel ClosureTable component incompatible with MS SQL Server (2014)

Tags: laravel, components

I am evaluating a Laravel/PHP component meant to manage tree data in a SQL database using the "closure Table" design pattern. Code repository: https://github.com/franzose/ClosureTable

Oh my, this component gives me endless headaches. After some installation hickups (Lifetime cost: 2 days ...) I got one little step forward, and ran into what seems to be a really serious compatibility problem with the Microsoft SQL server. When the database ist created through the migration provided by the component, I get the following fatal SQL error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'pages_parent_id_foreign' on
>   table 'pages' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
>   DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints. (SQL: alter table "pages" add constraint
>   "pages_parent_id_foreign" foreign key ("parent_id") references "pages"
>   ("id") on delete set null)

A similar problem has been described here:
[Foreign key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Anyone having an idea how I can fix this, without breaking the component?

Thnx, Armin.

P.S. I also filed an issue hoping to get teh developer's attraction: [Link to Git issue](https://github.com/franzose/ClosureTable/issues/192)