# EF Core Cascade Delete

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Context: Visual Studio, Blazor .NET 5, Azure SQL Server

I have an entity with two FK. If I delete a record in one the FK tables I get the typical Referencing error.
In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete it seems to say the Cascade Delete is the default.
When I generate a new Migration (add-migration cascade) there is no

```
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
.IsRequired();
```

... attached to the FK properties of the entity in question in the Migration documents generated.

1. Is there an Attribute that can be applied to the FK property in the entity class?
2. Is there some other way of doing this in code?
3. How do I modify the migration documentation to entrench th?

Comment: Is this code first?  It's tagged SQL Server which, unless I missed a memo, defaults cascade delete to off.  You could set it at the database level.  Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: You can always generate new "empty" migration file and alter the table y writing EF Core or raw SQL.

Comment: Yes it is Code-First. There is an entity Activity with two dependant entities (Helper and Round) (they are properties of the first entity). For the Helper property of  an Activity, it makes sense that when Helper is deleted, the corresponding property in Activity is set to  null, as it allows another Helper to be selected for the Activity. But if a Round is deleted, then the need is for the Activity to be deleted. Currently as per a Helper deletion, the Round is nulled in the Activity upon a Round deletion.  I'm trying to follow Fabio's method. doc ref says can't set CascadeDelete in SQLSvr???

Comment: I'd appreciate some info on exactly how to the empty migration approach, Have created an empty migration called cascadeDelete.  Do I modify the snapshot, the 20210201060139_cascadeDelete.cs or even the designer.  Have tried just the snapshot thus far without success. added .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade) to the Round property of Activity. No joy with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing .. I did it in code

> ```
>     public async Task DeleteRound(int Id)
>    {
>        var round = _context.Rounds.Where(e => e.Id==Id).Include(e => e.Activitys).First();
>        _context.Rounds.Remove(round);
>        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
>    }
> ```

I had to add the following to the Round Class:

> ```
>    public IList<Activity> Activitys { get; } = new List<Activity>();
> ```

No further code required. No need to populate the list as above. It seems that EF is doing it seamlessly. No need to annotate the Migration files.