# ef core configure on delete behavior by data annotation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, relational-database, ef-core-2.2

Trying to achieve foreign key on delete behavior by data annotation.
I tried in the following way

Below are my model configuration

```
 public class Course
    {
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public int CourseType { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }

    public class Staff
    {
        public int StaffId { get; set; }
        public string StaffName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
```

When the migration is added it generated below

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Staff",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    StaffId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    StaffName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    CourseId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    IsActive = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    IsDeleted = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Staff", x => x.StaffId);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Staff_Courses_CourseId",
                        column: x => x.CourseId,
                        principalTable: "Courses",
                        principalColumn: "CourseId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

Now want to change ondelete behavior (not manually) as required instead of cascade.
I know we can achieve it using fluent API but wondering can we achieve it  using data annotation ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in EF Core 7 with the [DeleteBehaviorAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/mapping-attributes#deletebehaviorattribute). If you are not in EF Core 7 then you can use this below code described in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326769/entity-framework-core-delete-cascade-and-required). Otherwise you have to use FluentAPI.

```
foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
{
    relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
}
```