# Multiple 'ON DELETE CASCADE' constraints for identical foreign key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cascade

### Scenario

Imagine a chat server with conversations `C` and multiple posts `P` in each conversation. A user can reply to a post. This data should be stored as `reply := (original_post_id, replyer_post_id)`.

To mimic this I have the tables `P` (posts) and `R` (replies):

```
CREATE TABLE P (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    -- more data ...
)

CREATE TABLE R (
    orig_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    repl_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY orig_id REFERENCES P(id),
    FOREIGN KEY repl_id REFERENCES P(id),
)
```

---

### Problem

If I want to automaically delete all associated `R`-entries upon deletion inside `P`, I would change the last two lines of `R`'s definition to:

```
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY orig_id REFERENCES P(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY repl_id REFERENCES P(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
)
```

However, I recieve the following error:

> Introducing `FOREIGN KEY` constraint [...] on table [...] may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify `ON DELETE NO ACTION` or `ON UPDATE NO ACTION`, or modify other `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

---

### Question

Why exactly am I recieving this error? Technically it is not a cycle as neither `R.orig_id` nor `R.repl_id` are referenced by any other table (thus possbibly creating a cycle).
I furthermore cannot see why multiple cascade paths should be an issue, as the deletion procedure would be as follows:

- Delete an entry from `P` with `P.id = 1234`
- Delete **any** entry from `R` with `R.repl_id = 1234` **or** `R.orig_id = 1234`

Should I somehow constrain the columns `R.repl_id` and `R.orig_id` not to be equal?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/852047/575376

Comment: I also don't see an issue with cycles, but I do see multiple cascade paths.  Why do you have two foreign keys pointing to the same primary key?  I think the easy fix here is to just maintain a single foreign key.

Comment: Well, a reply is a post (identified by its ID) on an other post (also by its ID). A valid reply would only be a tuple of two valid post IDs (both being represented by `P.id`).

Comment: Table `R` lets you tie together _any_ pairs of posts in `P`. What happens when you have ( 1, 2 ) and ( 2, 1 )? Cycles like that could be arbitrarily long and branch into bizarre shapes. That may not be allowed in your application, but the database isn't "aware" of that. Since a post is presumably either independent or a reply to a _single_ post you could dispense with table `R` and add a `ReplyToPostId` column to `P` with a default value of `NULL`.

Comment: I think you have to adding Primary Key :
PRIMARY KEY pk_r_table (orig_id, repl_id),

Comment: @HABO I don't see the problem with that: even if I had ( 1, 2 ) and ( 2, 1 ), whenever I delete any post (`P.id = 2`) I expect **all** the relationships where it's directly involved (`R.repl_id = 2` or `R.orig_id = 2`) to be deleted, it shouldn't lead to any cycles, as deleting rows in R doesn't affect P, but the other way around... I still don't understand this error