# DELETE in table where is a FK referring to the PK of the current table

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

There are two tables:

[image]

In the `EMPLOYEES` table, `EMPLOYEE_ID` is the primary key.
`MGR_ID` is a manager identifier and refers to `EMPLOYEE_ID`.
`DEPT_ID` is the foreign key to the `DEPARTMENT_ID` column of the `DEPARTMENTS` table.

In the `DEPARTMENTS` table, `DEPARTMENT_ID` is the primary key.

When I execute the following command

```
DELETE
FROM departments
WHERE department_id = 40;
```

I get this result

> 0 rows affect

My foreign key have referential integrity is limited - `ON DELETE CASCADE` . Why DELETE does not be cascade?
Does it matter what `MGR_ID` is the refers to `EMPLOYEE_ID` column of this table?

Comment: If the foreign key is proper setup, then you cannot delete from `DEPARTMENTS` while there are rows in `EMPLOYEES` with that ID. That is normal and it saved you from corrupting your database. So what is your question actually ?

Comment: Did you got an error like this one `The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "ForeignKey_Name". The conflict occurred in database "YourDataBase", table "EMPLOYEES", column 'MGR_ID'` ?

Comment: Hi,  GuidoG.

No, I not get errore. While working in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I get only the result: 0 rows affect

Comment: 0 rows affected means that it did't find any row to delete, the foreign key would throw the error that @GuidoG mentioned... Or your data is different or you have an instead of delete trigger in the middle

Comment: Does your departments table have any triggers?

Comment: Can you show us the table schemas, including the foreign key constraint ? Its hard to say without seeing how the keys where setup. Also show any triggers on this tables

Comment: Is EMPLOYEES.MGR_ID a foreign key to EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID?  and, if so, do you have ON DELETE CASCADE set up there?  Because, if you only have it on the DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID to EMPLOYEES.DEPT_ID, it'll get blocked when it tries to delete Bob on the first cascade.

Comment: By the way, though I don't think you'd have a problem with this particular schema (just not hiring and firing that frequently, I'd suspect) don't use ON DELETE CASCADE.  If there is any level of volume, it'll create locking situations that are difficult to diagnose, and the potential for fat-finger errors exponentially increases due to the amount of side effects that you can't really see from the query window.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete it because it has dependencies to the primary key, if you'd like to still continue you either have to break the dependencies or delete the dependencies in the query as well.

Comment: Hi, Arasto Sahbaei. 

If on the constraint on column MGR_ID is ON DELETE CASCADE.
Does this not affect the result?


Does it matter what DEPT_ID is the foreign key to the DEPARTMENT_ID column of this table?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths?rq=1

Comment: Never ever break dependencies !!! They are there for a reason. In this case it saved him from corrupting his database

Answer (score 0):

If your table `Employees` has the statement similar to this:

```
CONSTRAINT Dept_ID_FK__Departments FOREIGN KEY (department_id ) 
    REFERENCES dbo.Departments(department_id )
```

It means you cannot delete like you've written, because `SQL Server` will not allow you to delete the rows with `department_id = 40`:

```
DELETE
FROM departments
WHERE department_id = 40;
```

As there are rows in `Employee` table with `DeptId` which are linked to `Departments` table. As it will get the data into the corrupt state.

Answer (score 0):

What happend is simple referential integrety that stepped up, and your delete statement is correctly blocked by the database.

Suppose you where able to delete the row in `DEPARTMENTS` with `Department_ID = 40`
Then in your table `EMPLOYEES` there would be at least one row that points to a department that does not exist !!!
In other words, your database would be corrupt.
That is the purpose of foreign keys, to make sure there is no way at all to corrupt your database like that.

The only way to delete this row from `DEPARTMENTS` is to first uncouple all rows in `EMPLOYEES` from that Department_ID.

So, either you couple all employees first to a different department

```
update EMPLOYEE
Set    Dept_ID = 20 -- or some other...
where  Dept_ID = 40
```

or you delete all employees

```
delete from EMPLOYEE where Dept_ID = 40
```

And now you can delete your Department

But I still dont understand why you did not get an errormessage...

Comment: My foreign key have referential integrity is limited - `ON DELETE CASCADE` . Why DELETE does not be cascade?

Comment: Can you show us the table schemas, including the foreign key constraint ? Its hard to say without seeing how the keys where setup