# Can i delete user's questions and answers if i delete the user SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

I have user table questions table and answers table on SQL.
I want to add foreign key with on delete cascade on questions user_ID foreign key and answers user_ID foreign key that when i delete a user all his questions and answers are also deleted. But SQL says:

> > Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__questions__usID__1BC821DD' on table 'questions' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

How can i do that.

Comment: Please show us your existing code.

Comment: I did this:alter table questions
add constraint user_question_id_fkey
foreign key (usID)
references users (uID)
on delete cascade; but when i tried the same for answer table it returned the error

Comment: SQL Server does not support this kind of cascade delete. You will need to either use an SP to handle this or a trigger.

Comment: Can you give me an example because i am new at sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Foreign key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a foreign key on the `questions` (resp: `answers`) table that references the `users` table and that deletes all questions (resp: answers) of a user when it is removed from the `users` table.

This should work as per design:

```
alter table answers add constraint answers_users 
    foreign key(user_id)
    references users(user_id)
    on delete cascade
;

alter table questions add constraint questions_users 
    foreign key(user_id)
    references users(user_id)
    on delete cascade
;
```

Consider **[this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cd49d92ab8be31385fbc3ec345d3c8ce)**:

```
-- create the tables
create table users (user_id int primary key);
create table questions(question_id int primary key, user_id int);
create table answers(answer_id int primary key, user_id int);

-- add the constraints
alter table answers add constraint answers_users 
    foreign key(user_id)
    references users(user_id)
    on delete cascade
;
alter table questions add constraint questions_users 
    foreign key(user_id)
    references users(user_id)
    on delete cascade
;

-- insert a few records - we have two users: 1 and 2
insert into users values (1), (2);
insert into questions values(1, 1), (2, 2);
insert into answers values(1, 1), (2, 2);

-- now delete user 1
delete from users where user_id = 1;

-- the corresponding record was removed from "questions"
select * from questions;

question_id | user_id
----------: | ------:
          2 |       2

-- ... and it was removed from "answers" as well
select * from answers;

answer_id | user_id
--------: | ------:
        2 |       2
```

Comment: It worked on a new database but not in my current database. Anyways thanks for the help