# How can these constraints may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, cascade

Note: this question is more about database design and SQL Server than specific ORMDB like EF Core.

I have a database schema that looks like this:

[image]

Using EF Core Migration, all the SQL statements can be run until the very last constraint (`FK_BookReleases_Nicknames_NicknameId`). The previous FK `FK_BookReleases_Books_BookId` could be added.

The error I receive is (as many other articles on SO):

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_BookReleases_Nicknames_NicknameId' on table 'BookReleases' may
>   cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

My question is, where is the flaw on that design? I cannot understand under any logic such situation happens. And what is the proper fix? I see many suggested changing `ON DELETE` action but not specific on which FK and what other action I should use.

Worse, even already read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3548225/653457) I still don't understand how it could be a problem, and how would his proposed solution fits in the above schema.

Comment: See the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths/3548225#3548225

There is really nothing wrong with the design, it's an implementation restriction.

Comment: @GeorgeBarwood Sorry maybe night shift clouds my mind. I actually quoted that answer in my question, the problem is, I cannot understand how his workaround works. i.e on the above case, how should my tables look like? Or what FK Action should I change?

Comment: I think I will set No Action on Author-Nickname FK relationship, assuming that Nickname will never be deleted, or that if Author is ever be deleted, all nicknames must be deleted first.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Put what is needed to ask your question directly in it. If you are trying to ask about uderstanding that presentation then make that clear & quote what's needed to explain about how you are stuck. Or comment on that post for clarification. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please for code questions give a [mre].

Comment: "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths" Read the manual--multiple paths are not allowed. Find out what it means by "path". Follow the cascade paths from Author--there are two to AuthorRelease. How are you stuck in this process? Or if you are stuck following the solution per your comment then your question is not actually what your post says it is so edit your post to ask the 1 question you want to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to multiple cascading paths from Author (Grand Parent) to BookRelease (Grand Child). There are two cascading paths:

1. Author -> Book -> BookRelease
2. Author -> Nickname -> BookRelease

This is discussed in detail in the [post in MSSQLTips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/)

[image: Multiple Cascading Paths]

So, the way to handle this is:

1. Disable the ON DELETE CASCAE and choose NOACTION as the foreign key creation.
2. Create INSTEAD OF DELETE TRIGGERS in Author(GrandParent), Book(Child1), Nickname(Child2) tables to handle the deletion of parent keys in the child tables.

> - **Grand Parent deletion :** Delete in GrandChild, followed by Child1,
>     followed by Child2,
> - **Child1 deletion:** Delete in GrandChild, followed
>     by Child1
> - **Child2 deletion:** Delete in GrandChild, followed by Child2