# Foreign key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, foreign-keys

I'm doing a project using ASP.NET Core MVC. I created my models and when I update the migration I got this error.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Branch_Countries_CountriesId' on table 'Branch' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints

I went through the code and I hope there is nothing wrong with the foreign key assigned.

I hope the issue is `Branch` and `Country` both contain the `CountryId` for the foreign key. It should be connected to both tables connected with the `Country` table. But here it says can't create the table because of the cycle or multiple cascade paths.

So how to avoid this and do the migrations? Or the way I connected 3 tables are wrong?

Could you help me with this?

```
public class Countries
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Country_Name { get; set; }
    public string Country_Code { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; } = "N/A";
    public bool Status { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public int CreateBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Province> Province { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Branch> Branch { get; set; }

    public Countries()
    {
        Province = new List<Province>();
        Branch = new List<Branch>();
    }
}

public class Province
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Province_Name { get; set; }
    public string Province_Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Countries")]
    public int Country_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Countries Countries { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; } = "N/A";
    public bool Status { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public int CreateBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Cities> Cities { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Branch> Branch { get; set; }

    public Province()
    {
        Cities = new List<Cities>();
        Branch = new List<Branch>();
    }
}

public class Cities
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City_Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Province")]
    public int Province_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Province Province { get; set; }
    public string Postal_Code { get; set; }
    public string Istat_Code { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; } = "N/A";
    public bool Status { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public int CreateBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Branch> Branch { get; set; }

    public Cities()
    {
        Branch = new List<Branch>();
    }
}

public class Branch
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public int City_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Cities Cities { get; set; }
    public int Province_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Province Province { get; set; }
    public int Country_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Countries Countries { get; set; }
    public string LocationEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string LocationContactNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public int CreateBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<EmployeeLocations> EmployeeLocations { get; set; }

    public Branch()
    {
        EmployeeLocations = new List<EmployeeLocations>();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it’s not an issue. CountryId is referenced in province table as well. So it’s asking you that what do you want to do when you delete a record from branch.

Comment: A `Branch` should not have a `ProvinceId` or a `CountryId`. As it stands, you could potentially link a `Branch` to a `Province` that does not contain the `City` it's linked to and the same for `Country`. Link it to a `City`, which is linked to a `Province`, which is linked to a `Country`.

Comment: @viveknuna how to avoid this? Because of that reason migration not applying to the database

Comment: @DevBeginner why do you need countryid in branch? You should remove it because you already have province is in branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is very simple. You should remove `ContryId` from `Branch`, because `ContryId` is already referenced in `Province`.

Answer (score 1):

It was caused by multiple cascade paths:

Branch-Country-Province-City

Branch-Province-City

Branch-City

You could check this case for more details:[Foreign key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths/852047#852047)