# Problem foreign key between tables in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC & EF Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I have a problem in my new project, I work in ASP.NET Core 6 and Entity Framework Core. In my project I have 10 tables, the problem comes from the relation between all the tables. Last time I posted a part of my project, you proposed to me some changes and advice, I make the changes but I found another type of problem, I tried very hard to solve it but I cannot.

I decided to share with you all my project and I need some helps please.

The project is about a school management system

Models:

```
public class Classe
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  ClassName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Examen> Examens { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TeacherSubject> TeacherSubjects { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Fee> Fees { get; set; }
    public ICollection<StudentAttendence> StudentAttendence { get; set; }
}

public class Examen
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Marks { get; set; }

    public virtual Classe Classe { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Classe))]
    public int ClasseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Subject))]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
}

public class Expense
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ChargeAmount { get; set; }

    public virtual Classe Classe { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Classe))]
    public int ClasseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Subject))]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
}

public class Fee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FeeAmount { get; set; }

    public virtual Classe Classe { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Classe))]
    public int ClasseId { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string RollNo { get; set; }
    public string Adresse { get; set; }

    public virtual Classe Classe { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Classe))]
    public int ClasseId { get; set; }
}

public class StudentAttendence
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RollNo { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }

    public virtual Classe Classe { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Classe))]
    public int ClasseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Subject))]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Examen> Examens { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TeacherSubject> TeacherSubjects { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<StudentAttendence> StudentAttendence { get; set; }

    public virtual Classe Classe { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Classe))]
    public int ClasseId { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Adresse { get; set; }
    public string PassWord { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TeacherSubject> TeacherSubjects { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TeacherAttendence> TeacherAttendence { get; set; }
}

public class TeacherAttendence
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }

    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Teacher))]
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
}

public class TeacherSubject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Classe Classe { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Classe))]
    public int ClasseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Subject))]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Teacher))]
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
}
```

My `DbContext` :

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options):base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Classe> Classes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Examen> Examens { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TeacherSubject> TeacherSubjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Fee> Fees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentAttendence> StudentAttendences { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TeacherAttendence> TeacherAttendences { get; set; }
}
```

When I add a migration, I always get this problem :

> Introducing a FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Examens_Subjects_SubjectId' on the 'Exams' table may cause cycles or multiple cascad accesses. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Unable to create constraint or index.

I represented my database in Excel :

[image]

Can someone please help me to find how can I fix this  ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, I make some changes in my class DbContext

```
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Classe> Classes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Examen> Examens { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }

   public DbSet<Fee> Fees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentAttendence> StudentAttendences { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TeacherAttendence> TeacherAttendences { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Examen>().
            HasKey(x=> new {x.ClasseId, x.SubjectId});

        modelBuilder.Entity<Examen>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Classe)
            .WithMany(z=>z.Examens)
            .HasForeignKey(x=>x.ClasseId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Examen>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Subject)
            .WithMany(z => z.Examens)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.SubjectId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);


        modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Classe)
            .WithMany(z => z.Subjects)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ClasseId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);


        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your multi-cascade relationship. The easiest way is to cancel the relationship between `Classe` and `Subject`:

```
public class Classe
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Examen> Examens { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TeacherSubject> TeacherSubjects { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Fee> Fees { get; set; }
    public ICollection<StudentAttendence> StudentAttendence { get; set; }
}
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Examen> Examens { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TeacherSubject> TeacherSubjects { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<StudentAttendence> StudentAttendence { get; set; }

    //public virtual Classe Classe { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey(nameof(Classe))]
    //public int ClasseId { get; set; }
}
```

For details, you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3548225/18789859).