# How can i use 2 tables in stored procedure when deleting?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i would like to use two tables in my deleting stored procedure. Normally, i can write the query like this:

> delete * from table_1 x, table_2 y
>   where x.ID = y.ID

But i coundn't do it with stored procedure(as you know=)

please help..

Comment: sorry, i should say.. Microsoft SQL Server 2008 -- Express

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783726/how-do-i-delete-from-multiple-tables-using-inner-join-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all answers, i could do it with using "renegm" and "Sebastian Piu"s comments.
Yes, i'd like to delete all rows from both tables so i did it like that:

> USE DB
>
> SET ANSI_NULLS ON
> GO
> SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
> GO
> ALTER PROCEDURE delUser
> (
> @ID int
> )
> AS
> DELETE FROM Table_1
> FROM Table_1
> INNER JOIN Table_2 AS Y
> ON Table_1.ID = Y.ID
> AND Y.ID = @ID
> DELETE FROM Table_2
> WHERE Table_2.ID = @ID

It's working but is it really solution i don't know exactly =))

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table_1
    FROM table_1 
        INNER JOIN table_2 AS Y
            ON table_1.id = Y.id
```

Comment: This will only delete rows from table_1. The OP wishes to delete all rows from both tables with only one delete statement, which after multiple tries, I think he'd better go with the link in Sebastian Piu's comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct ID
into #temp
from table_1
join table_2
on table_1.ID = table_2.ID

delete table_1
where ID in (select * from #temp)

delete table_2
where ID in (select * from #temp)

drop table #temp
```

simplest + no confusion

Answer (score 0):

Delete only is for a table.

MSDN description for delete

> DELETE (Transact-SQL)
>
> **Removes rows from a table or view.**

if u want always delete from table2 when delete from table1, u can use trigger on table1.

see this link: http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=322160&postcount=5