# Database structure of product images

Tags: postgresql

At the moment I have 3 table: products, images, products_images.
So, basically I store product's images in "products_images" table.
When a product is updated, I remove all rows from "products_images" table related to that product, and add new one.
Also, I need to save the order, now the order is how they are stored in database.

Is this correct approach? Or maybe there are a better database structure to store product's images?

Comment: You can have one column in product_images table isDeleted once you add or remove anything check in the table if the link between product and image already exist then update the bit to 0 or 1 as needed. And for new records add a row with default bit isDeleted 0.

Comment: Read the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762582/deleting-related-rows-in-a-many-to-many-relationship) by GBN.

Answer (score 1):

**Entity relationship consideratoin**

If you don't share images between products (never use one image for more than 1 product) then your relationship is really One-To-Many and there is no need for `products_images` junction table. This would simplify your model to:

- Products (id_product, ...)
- Images (id_image, ..., id_product)

And `id_product` in `Images` table would have a Foreign Key pointing at `Products(id_product)`. That way, when you want to detach all images from a product you would simply run an update statement:

```
UPDATE images SET id_product = NULL WHERE id_product = ?
```

---

**Sorting consideration**

Since you need to save the order in which images are stored in the database, depending on what columns you have in `Images` table you could use for example `id_image` if it was declared as `SERIAL` (auto-incremented integer value). As a rule of thumb in PostgreSQL (where there are no clustered indexes) remember that if you need the output sorted, you need to do that yourself (example: add an `ORDER BY id_image`) at the end.