# Create a table with duplicate values, and use a CTE (Common Table Expression )to delete those duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008

Create a table with duplicate values, and use a CTE (Common Table Expression )to delete those duplicate values.

=>
Would some one please help me how to start it because i really don't understand the question.
Assume guess duplicate values can be chosen anything.

Comment: A CTE does not delete anything. I don't understand the question either. Creating a table with duplicated values is easy: `create table tbl as select 1 col1 from dual union all select 1 from dual` creates a table `tbl` with one column `col1` and two rows, both with the value 1 in that column.

Comment: This is like a question fragment. Does it have more that goes with it?

Comment: And are you using Oracle or SQL-Server?

Comment: Looks similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730226/deleting-duplicate-row-that-has-earliest-date/44730657#44730657.  Not sure the CTE's needed, but I suspect you could replace the subquery with a CTE.

Answer (score 1):

For MS SQL Server, this would work:

```sql
;with cte as
(
    select *
    , row_number() over (
        partition by [columns], [which], [should], [be], [unique]
        order by [columns], [to], [select], [what's], [kept]
    ) NoOfThisDuplicate
)
delete 
from cte
where NoOfThisDuplicate > 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/caf3c/13) (based on this question: [Deleting duplicate row that has earliest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730226/deleting-duplicate-row-that-has-earliest-date/44730657#44730657)).

**Explanation**

- Create a CTE
- Populate it with all rows from the table we want to delete
- Add a `NoOfThiDuplicate` column to that output
- Populate this value with the sequential number of this record with the group/partition of all records with the same values for columns `[columns], [which], [should], [be], [unique]`.
- The order of the numbering depends on the sort order of those records when sorted by columns `[columns], [to], [select], [what's], [kept]`
- We delete all records returned by the CTE except the first of each group (i.e. all except those with `NoOfThisDuplicate=1`).

Comment: Thank you your for clear explanation. Would you please help me how to learn sql for beginners. do you any links to follow up sir @JohnLBevan

Comment: @Randy a good place to start is https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/.  Also see https://www.slant.co/topics/890/~best-online-resources-for-learning-sql

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  How about watching videos? I watched it on youtube but different answers. will be vice to have smooth series of video with clear and easy understanding.

Comment: @Randy; sure; use whatever works best for you.  I'm not familiar with any SQL Server tutorial video series myself, but I'm sure there are some out there; ultimately browse, try things out & decide if they work for you / if you feel you're progressing.  If you are, stick with it, if not, browse for something else.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
  SELECT LEVEL   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
UNION ALL
  SELECT 2*LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

**Query 1**:

This will select the values removing duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM   test_data
```

But it does not use a CTE.

**Query 2**:

So, we can put it in a sub-query factoring clause (the name used in the Oracle documentation which corresponds to the SQL Server Common Table Expression)

```
WITH unique_values ( value ) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM   test_data
)
SELECT * FROM unique_values;
```

**Query 3**:

The sub-query factoring clause was pointless in the previous example ... so doing it a different way:

```
WITH row_numbers ( value, rn ) AS (
  SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY value ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   test_data
)
SELECT value
FROM   row_numbers
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Will select the rows where it the first instance of each value found.

**Delete Query**:

But that didn't delete the rows ...

```
DELETE FROM test_data
WHERE  ROWID IN (
  WITH row_numbers ( rid, rn ) AS (
    SELECT ROWID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY value ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
    FROM   test_data
  )
  SELECT rid
  FROM   row_numbers
  WHERE  rn > 1
);
```

Which uses the `ROWID` pseudocolumn to match rows for deletion.