# Advanced table deduping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

have a question... I have a table that has over 2 billion rows. Many are duplicates but there is a column (varchar) that has a validity date in a format such as 201806.

I want to dedupe the table BUT keep the most current date.

ex.

```
ID,fname, lname, addrees, city, state, zip, validitydate
1,steve,smith, pob 123, miami, fl. 33081,201709
2,steve,smith, pob 123, miami, fl. 33081,201010
3,steve,smith, pob 123, miami, fl. 33081,201809
4.steve,smith, pob 123, miami, fl. 33081,201201
```

I only want to keep: steve,smith, pob 123, miami, fl. 33081,201809 as it is the most current. If I run the below, it dedups, but it's a crap-shoot which one is left in the table as  I cannot add the validityDate as the tsql will then look as all of them as unique.

How can I make it so it dedups but calculates to keep the most current date as the final entry?

thanks in advance.

```
WITH Records AS 
(
SELECT fname, lname, addrees, city, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
  PARTITION BY fname, lname, addrees, city, state, zip, 
    validitydate by ID) AS RecordInstance 
FROM PEOPLE where lastname like 'S%'
)
DELETE
 FROM Records 
WHERE
 RecordInstance > 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting duplicate row that has earliest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730226/deleting-duplicate-row-that-has-earliest-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by month (descending) so the `RecordInstance` will be `1` for the most current one:

```
WITH Records AS (
  SELECT fname, lname, addrees, city,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
       PARTITION BY fname, lname, addrees, city, state, zip
       ORDER BY validitydate DESC -- Add this to order correctly!
     ) AS RecordInstance
  FROM PEOPLE where lastname like 'S%' 
)
DELETE FROM Records WHERE RecordInstance > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The delete will also work with just the ROW_NUMBER in the CTE.  Which is ordered by the descending validitydate. So that the most recent month will have row_number 1 and you can delete those > 1

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fname, lname, addrees, city, state, zip ORDER BY validitydate DESC, ID DESC) AS rn
   FROM PEOPLE
   WHERE lname like 'S%'
)
DELETE 
FROM CTE
WHERE rn > 1;
```

A test can be found [here](http://rextester.com/YKJVP89919)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to an article I wrote regarding this very issue.

https://sqlfundamentals.wordpress.com/delete-duplicate-rows-in-t-sql/

Hope this helps.