# Looking for best possible way to combine 2 SQL queries

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to combine 2 sql query 1: SELECT and 2: DELETE. Any inputs on how i can implement that?

The output from SELECT is given into WHERE clause in DELETE. Please refer code snippet.

```
select id from table1 where id_hash IN( select id_hash from table1 where name='stack' group by id_hash having count(*)>1
```

The output(id) of above SELECT is passed to DELETE

```
delete from table1 where id in (<id from SELECT>)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KenWhite That will get the "can't specify target table for update" query.

Comment: Why do you need to combine the queries? Can't you just copy the `WHERE` clause? `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE name = 'stack'`

Comment: @Barmar: I hate MySQL. :-)

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the comments. I edited my code where in reality its a complex subquery. The reason to combine is an early effort to automate(Reduce steps of execution) I am a newbie to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to someone who has asked a similar question:

[How to write a SQL DELETE statement with a SELECT statement in the WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548751/how-to-write-a-sql-delete-statement-with-a-select-statement-in-the-where-clause)

Here is an example from that thread. Credit to user @AlexW

```
DELETE FROM tableA
WHERE ROWID IN 
  ( SELECT q.ROWID
    FROM tableA q
    INNER JOIN tableB u on (u.qlabel = q.entityrole AND u.fieldnum = q.fieldnum) 
    WHERE (LENGTH(q.memotext) NOT IN (8,9,10) OR q.memotext NOT LIKE '%/%/%')
    AND (u.FldFormat = 'Date'));
```

Comment: If you've found an answer already here, you should be flagging the original question as a duplicate instead of posting an answer from it.