# Delete data from table without creating temporary table

Tags: mysql, database, join, select, left-join

I have three tables, that match the following diagram:

[image: visualization of the tables]

And I need to delete some data from join_table, where a label column(table_right) and name column(table_left) match some criteria.

My solution is to use a temporary table:

```
create temporary table if not exists data_for_deletion
(select jt.id
 from join_table jt
          left join table_left tableLeft on jt.table_left_id = tableLeft.id
          left join table_right tableRight on jt.table_right_id = tableRight.id
 where tableLeft.name = 'name' and tableRight.label = 'label');

delete from join_table where id in (select id from data_for_deletion);
```

My question is: is there any other way to do such deletion without creating a temporary table?

Comment: Yes, use your select as a subquery  in your last query.. . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548751/how-to-write-a-sql-delete-statement-with-a-select-statement-in-the-where-clause/43461074  or with a delete with inner http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/

Comment: No, I can not. When I put select statement in the last query, I have following error: You can't specify target table 'join_table' for update in FROM clause.

Comment: check the examples... or with a delete with inner join http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use MySQL's multi-table [`DELETE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) syntax:

```
DELETE jt
FROM join_table jt
JOIN table_left tl ON jt.table_left_id = tl.id
JOIN table_right tr ON jt.table_right_id = tr.id
WHERE tl.name = 'name' AND tr.label = 'label'
```

Note that since you have a `WHERE` clause which is dependent on columns in `table_left` and `table_right` there is no point in using a `LEFT JOIN` as it will be converted to an `INNER JOIN` anyway (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-optimization.html)).