# MS Access: Run SELECT query before running DELETE query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using a `SELECT` query in MS Access to select data from two tables.

In a second step I want to delete entries from a third table that are already displayed in the results of that select query. Therefore I wrote a `DELETE` query that deletes all records from the third table that show up in the result of the `SELECT` query.

Simple question: Is it enough to run the delete query from VBA code or do I need to run the `SELECT` query before, to get up-to-date results?

Table 1 and 2 are linked tables and they are updated daily, so the results of the `SELECT` query should differ, too, before I run the `DELETE` query.

Thanks in advance!

Update: It is two different queries, not a `SELECT` statement within a delete query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a SQL DELETE statement with a SELECT statement in the WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548751/how-to-write-a-sql-delete-statement-with-a-select-statement-in-the-where-clause)

Comment: It doesn't, to be honest. It looks like they had a select statement within the delete query whereas I have two separate queries. I am quite new to MS Access and have never worked with SQL so maybe I just don't get the point...

Comment: The point is to make a single query that does everything you want in essentially one step. Then you don't have to worry about referencing one query from another or storing the results in a temp table or clearing the temp table when the final query is run. Using a single query will likely run quicker and use fewer resources, too. I understand this isn't a basic feature of SQL, but it's not too horribly advanced, either.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying. I'll try to apply the answers from the link to my case..

Comment: Edit question to post query SQL statements. If SELECT query is referenced in DELETE, then the SELECT will be 'run', no need to 'open' the object.

Comment: Could you post the SQL for your `delete` query, so that we can see how it references the results of your `select` query?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by placing both queries, i.e select query and delete query in a macro,

The macro will be like this
open query, under the properties options beneath, pick the  the select query
open query, under the properties options beneath, pick the  the delete query

save the macro.

You can then attach the macro to a command button on a form, then click to run the macro daily or any time you need it.