# Delete from two tables based on matching values returned from a select query

Tags: delete-row

I have 3 tables, ERA, RA and LOCS

with the following columns of interests in the respective tables

- ERA: REMOTE_ID, LOCS_KEY, CUR
- LOCS: LOCS_KEY
- RA: REMOTE_ID

What im trying to accomplish:

- 1 - Get rows where CUR = 0 in table ERA  ( This is easy enough to do)
- 2 - Then Delete from:

  - LOCS: rows matching LOCS_KEY found in 1
  - RA: rows matching REMOTE_ID from 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a SQL DELETE statement with a SELECT statement in the WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548751/how-to-write-a-sql-delete-statement-with-a-select-statement-in-the-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548751/how-to-write-a-sql-delete-statement-with-a-select-statement-in-the-where-clause) I linked, you can use the following statements to delete from `LOCS` and `RA`. Be aware that unless `LOCS_KEY` and `REMOTE_ID` are unique in the table, you may be deleting multiple rows in `LOCS` or `RA` for each match in `ERA`.

```sql
DELETE FROM LOCS
WHERE LOCS_KEY IN (SELECT LOCS_KEY FROM ERA WHERE CUR = 0);

DELETE FROM RA
WHERE REMOTE_ID IN (SELECT REMOTE_ID FROM ERA WHERE CUR = 0);
```

[Try it out!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/93fcbc/2)