# How to delete a row from a table using a join SQL

Tags: sql

```
DELETE FROM Table1
INNER JOIN View1 ON Table1.ID = View1.ID
WHERE Table1.ID = View1.ID;
```

error is SQL command not ended properly

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Delete using INNER JOIN with SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you do this depends on the dialect of SQL.  Here is a method that should work in any database:

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.Id in (select Id from View1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the table where you want to delete the records,

```
DELETE Table1                        -- <== this will delete records from Table1
FROM   Table1
       INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID;
```

Comment: Still not ended properly! I've edited the SQL, Table2 was actually a View.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE Table1
FROM   Table1
INNER JOIN View1
ON Table1.ID = View1.ID;
```