# DELETE - INNER JOIN - Sub Query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, delete-row

I have 3 tables as you can see:
[image]

The relationships between all 3 tables:

- `cal_events.id = cf_cal_events.model_id`
- `cf_cal_events.col_10 = source.ID_ELEMENT`

I want to delete data from `cal_events` and `cf_cal_events` if `ASUPPRIMER = '1'`

I know it's not very hard, but I'm not very familiar with JOINS and Sub-queries, but here are my tries to do it for `cal_events`:

```
DELETE FROM cal_events
INNER JOIN cf_cal_events ON cal_events.id = cf_cal_events.model_id
INNER JOIN source ON cf_cal_events.col_10 = source.ID_ELEMENT
WHERE source.ASUPPRIMER = '1';
```

AND

```
DELETE FROM cal_events
WHERE cal_events.id IN (
    SELECT cf_cal_events.model_id AS cal_events.id
    FROM cf_cal_events
    WHERE cf_cal_events.col_10 IN (
        SELECT ID_ELEMENT AS cf_cal_events.col_10
        FROM source
        WHERE source.ASUPPRIMER = '1'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good example for your problem:
[How to Delete using INNER JOIN with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server)

seems to me like it should be:

```
DELETE cal_events, cf_cal_events
FROM cal_events
INNER JOIN cf_cal_events ON cal_events.id = cf_cal_events.model_id
INNER JOIN source ON cf_cal_events.col_10 = source.ID_ELEMENT
WHERE source.ASUPPRIMER = '1';
```

Comment: The keyword USING is missing and "cal_events" table needs to be one table being joined.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that your queries are correct.  You just need to add the aliases to the delete statement:

```
DELETE cal_events, cf_cal_events
    FROM cal_events INNER JOIN
         cf_cal_events
         ON cal_events.id = cf_cal_events.model_id INNER JOIN
         source
         ON cf_cal_events.col_10 = source.ID_ELEMENT
WHERE source.ASUPPRIMER = '1';
```

Comment: It's exactly like my first code, with adding some details on your first line. However, it doesn't work....thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Find `multi table syntax` from the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html). Something like this

```
DELETE cal_events,
       cf_cal_events
  FROM cal_events
  JOIN cf_cal_events 
    ON cal_events.id = cf_cal_events.model_id
  JOIN source 
    ON cf_cal_events.col_10 = source.ID_ELEMENT
 WHERE source.ASUPPRIMER = '1';
```