# SQL Server - remove offsetting (money) rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some data - grouped by col LineNum - What I need to be able to do - is to remove all rows that off set each other with the negative and positive totalOrg values - so in any event that a row has 2 positive and one negative - remove both the positive and negative (totalOrg) row (where all other values beyond claimDetailID are equal) and leave the remaining positive...

```
DROP TABLE #table
CREATE TABLE #table (linenum int,   HCPCSOrg varchar(10),   reimbOrg money, unitsOrg           int, totalorg money, claimdetailID int,  comments varchar(500))
INSERT INTO #table
SELECT 1,   '84443',    22.93,  1,  -82.00  ,1072766,   'Status: N - No Other Lab Codes         In Claim - Reimb ClinLab'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   '84443',    22.93,  1,  82.00,  1072767,    'Status: N - No Other Lab Codes In Claim - Reimb ClinLab'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   '84443',    22.93,  1,  82.00,  1072768,    'Status: N - No Other Lab Codes     In Claim - Reimb ClinLab'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   '36415',    3.00,   1,  -15.00, 1072769,    'Status: N - No Other Lab Codes In Claim - Reimb ClinLab'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   '36415',    3.00,   1,  15.00,  1072770,    'Status: N - No Other Lab Codes In Claim - Reimb ClinLab'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   '36415',    3.00,   1,  15.00,  1072771,    'Status: N - No Other Lab Codes In Claim - Reimb ClinLab'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   '87621',    47.87,  1,  227.00, 1072772,    'Status: N - No Other Lab Codes In Claim - Reimb ClinLab'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   '85025',    10.61,  1,  40.00,  1072773,    'Status: N - No Other Lab Codes In Claim - Reimb ClinLab'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   '85025',    10.61,  1,  -40.00, 1072774,    'Status: N - No Other Lab Codes In     Claim - Reimb ClinLab'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,   'G0123',    27.64,  1,  -74.00, 1072775,    'Status: A - Found in ClinLab'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,   'G0123',    27.64,  1,  74.00,  1072776,    'Status: A - Found in ClinLab'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,   '85025',    10.61,  1,  40.00,  1072777,    'Status: N - No Other Lab Codes     In Claim - Reimb ClinLab'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,   'G0123',    27.64,  1,  74.00,  1072778,    'Status: A - Found in ClinLab'


SELECT * FROM #table
```

Comment: what version of sql server is this for?

Comment: And will rows be strictly sequential based on `claimDetailId` (ie, "duplicate" rows will always be "neighbors"), or could you have something like `82`, `15`, `-82`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
delete from [table]
from
(
  select p.claimdetailid p
  , n.claimdetailid n 
  from (
    select claimdetailid
    , linenum
    , hcpcsorg
    , reimborg
    , unitsorg
    , 0-totalorg totalorg
    , row_number() over (partition by linenum, hcpcsorg, reimborg, unitsorg, totalorg order by claimdetailid) r
    from [table]
    where totalorg >= 0
  ) p
  inner join (
    select claimdetailid
    , linenum
    , hcpcsorg
    , reimborg
    , unitsorg
    , totalorg
    , row_number() over (partition by linenum, hcpcsorg, reimborg, unitsorg, totalorg order by claimdetailid) r
    from [table]
    where totalorg <= 0
  ) n
  on n.linenum = p.linenum
  and n.hcpcsorg = p.hcpcsorg
  and n.reimborg = p.reimborg
  and n.unitsorg = p.unitsorg
  and n.totalorg = p.totalorg
  and n.r = p.r
) x
where [table].claimdetailid in (x.p, x.n);
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8910/4

**Explanation**

- The p and n subqueries list the positive and negative values (I've also includes zeros in both, since I guess these reconcile against themselves).
- The `row_number() over (partition by ....` ensures that where there is more than a 1:1 match, only matching pairs are removed (e.g. if I have 2 negative and 4 positive values with all else being equal, after deletion 2 positive values will remain.
- the double `from` at the start is a cheat's inner join for delete statements ([How to Delete using INNER JOIN with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server)) which allows me to compare the claimdetailid against both positive and negative values easily and the most efficiently of the available  options (e.g. compared to doing an `exists` statement or having to have the `x` subquery repeated, once to return positives and once for negatives.
- `0-totalorg` converts the negative value to a positive one, so it can be compared to the reconciling (offsetting) positive value in the inner join.

Comment: ps. I used [table] instead of #table simply to make it work in SQL Fiddle; in SQL Server you should be able to happily use either.

Comment: You're counting `0` valued rows in both subqueries (unlikely to be an issue here, but worth mentioning).  This fails if the first positive row doesn't match the first negative row - that is, if amounts were `15`, `74`, `-74`.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse counting zeros is deliberate (see first point in explanation); I assume the idea is to remove any rows which are for the same item and total zero; if you have a single row with value 0 it (literally) adds no value, so should be deleted.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse for your second point, I don't think it does.  I include `totalorg` in the `join` and the `partition by`, so rows with values `74` and `-74` are unaware of / unaffected by the row with value `15`.

Comment: The problem is your row numbers won't match for the `74`/`-74` pair.  You have tuples like `(1, 15)`, `(2, 74)`, `(1, -74)`, so they'll be thrown out by the join.  I missed that bit about 0.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I'm not sure I follow.  `hcpcsorg = 15` won't affect `hcpcsorg in (74, -74)`.  You've also put `(1,-74)`, `(2, 74)`; what are 1 and 2 there?  If they're line numbers / other fields from `[table]` it's correct that they don't join; they're in different sets.  If I've misunderstood please can you provide a sql fiddle link to demonstrate the potential issue?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse; apologies - you're right - just noticed that contrary to what I'd said above, I didn't include `hcpcsorg` in the `partition by`; good spot!

Comment: You need the reversal of| and n.totalorg = p.totalorg | to|  and 0-n.totalorg = p.totalorg |

Comment: @user2067753 correct - only I take care of that in the select statement of the `p` subquery (I figured it's probably more efficient to do it there than on the join itself; though in reality SQL's probably smart enough to optimise either way).

Comment: No I mean - assuming the rest of the `PARTITION BY` matches, if there's any differing amount it's going to throw the generation of the row number off.  [I've modified your fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/554c4/1), so that all `linenum = 3` have the same partition, so only the amount is different.

Comment: ok, I see it now, but the sqlfiddle I visited didn't do it that way (a mismatch)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - think we crossed threads; I corrected myself & the code in my later comment.  Thanks again for spotting.

Comment: @user2067753 - in my original version I had the `0-n.totalorg=p.totalorg` code in the join; later I revised both the code above and SQL Fiddle to include the `0-totalorg` in the subquery instead (after a rethink on which was likely to be more efficient; though as mentioned I doubt there's anything in it).  Please check latest versions above.