# Spring Dao says bad SQL grammar - syntax error

Tags: mysql, spring

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar     [DELETE
>   model_state_history FROM model_state_history INNER JOIN model ON
>   model_state_history.model_id = model.id WHERE model.package_id = ?];
>   nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL
>   statement "DELETE model_state_history FROM[*] model_state_history
>   INNER JOIN model ON model_state_history.model_ID = model.ID WHERE
>   model.PACKAGE_ID = ? "; SQL statement:

And it throws the above in the output. For my eyes, I don't see a syntax error. I am using MySQL database. Is there anything which is obviously wrong in SQL syntax above?

Using the DELETE FROM syntax gives the syntax error too.

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE FROM
>   model_state_history INNER JOIN model ON model_state_history.model_id =
>   model.id WHERE model.package_id = ?]; nested exception is
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "DELETE
>   FROM model_STATE_HISTORY INNER[*] JOIN model ON
>   model_STATE_HISTORY.model_ID = model.ID WHERE model.PACKAGE_ID = ? ";
>   SQL statement: DELETE FROM model_state_history INNER JOIN model ON
>   model_state_history.model_id = model.id WHERE model.package_id = ?
>   [42000-176]

And this is the piece of code that is being run

```
  @Transactional
  private int deleteAllModels(Long packageId) throws DataAccessException {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource).update(
        "DELETE FROM model_state_history INNER JOIN model ON model_state_history.version_id = model.id WHERE model.package_id = :package_id",
        ImmutableMap.of("package_id", packageId));
```

Comment: instead of `DELETE model_state_history FROM model_state_history` it should be `DELETE FROM model_state_history`

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran Try `DELETE model_state_history FROM model_state_history ...`. See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

On second thought, I think you might have a problem with the JOIN syntax. You're writing

> DELETE FROM ... INNER JOIN ... ON msh.version_id = m.id **WHERE** m.package_id = :package_id

I'd think that `WHERE` should be an `AND` instead, so the query would become:

```
"DELETE FROM model_state_history INNER JOIN model 
 ON model_state_history.version_id = model.id AND model.package_id = :package_id"
```

since the `WHERE` refers back to the `DELETE` statement, which doesn't have the `model` table in it's "scope".

Cheers,