# How to delete all rows from another table that are connected with the main one?

Tags: sql

I tried something like this, but it does only delete the categories so far.

```
DELETE s, i 
FROM imgbox_categories s 
INNER JOIN imgbox_images i 
ON s.category_id = i.fk_category_id 
WHERE category_id = @id
```

Additionaly I get an error

```
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (delete join is at least not ANSI SQL...)

Comment: I can't see ',' in the SQL

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @User2012384 Comma is in the first line

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't really know ._ .. Visual Studio, not sure which one is it then, mssql?

Comment: VisualStudio is a programming IDE which probably can support any DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't tag any DBMS involved, you can use `EXISTS()` which is `ANSI SQL`:

```
DELETE from imgbox_categories 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM imgbox_images  i
             WHERE imgbox_categories.category_id = i.fk_category_id )
 AND imgbox_categories.category_id = @id
```

Comment: I'm not sure which one is it... I'm using visual studio, could it be mssql?

Comment: Doesn't matter, did you try this query?

Comment: Yes, just tried it     `Incorrect syntax near 's'.
    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.`

Comment: Still removes only category from imgbox_categories but none of row was delete from imgbox_images. At least there is no error now :P

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be correct, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server).

You are trying to delete from two tables at the same time, I think you cannot do this. Here is the comma where you get the error: `DELETE s, i`

If you delete from `imgbox_categories` with your query and then from `imgbox_images` using a simple query, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want delete from 2 tables, you can use 2 SQL queries:

```
DELETE FROM imgbox_categories WHERE category_id = @id;
DELETE FROM imgbox_images WHERE fk_category_id = @id;
```