# Can i use a JOIN with DELETE clause in SQL

Tags: sql

I wonder is the following query valid in sql:

```
DELETE FROM Reporters 
JOIN Cases ON Reporters.CaseId = Cases.ID 
WHERE Cases.Court = @Court
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near join

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server? If so, your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Standard SQL does not support a JOIN with a DELETE statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mention from which table that you wanted to delete from. (the solution is specific to SQL Server)

```
DELETE re --if you wanted to delete the cases replace `re` with `ca`
FROM Reporters re 
JOIN Cases ca ON re.CaseId = ca.ID 
    WHERE ca.Court = @Court
```

Comment: Very product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE r
FROM reporters as r
INNER JOIN cases as c
ON r.CaseId = c.ID 
    WHERE c.Court = @Court
```

Comment: Very product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you just have to specify Alias to your table and delete using it:

```
DELETE R
-- SELECT *
FROM Reporters AS R
INNER JOIN Cases AS C
    ON R.CaseId = C.ID
WHERE C.Court = @Court ;
```

Comment: Very product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you alias the tables like;

```
DELETE r
FROM Reporters AS r
INNER JOIN Cases AS c
    ON r.CaseId = c.ID
WHERE c.Court = @Court
```

Or you could use

```
DELETE FROM Reporters 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Cases WHERE Cases.ID = Reporters.CaseId AND Cases.Court = @Court)
```