# Using DELETE and joins in stored procedures

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to delete any record where the `FeeDueDate` is greater than 3 weeks but Im not sure how to go about implementing this. The problem seems to be with the join syntax.

```
    CREATE PROC spAreFeesOverDue 
    AS
    Delete 
    FROM Assignment.dbo.PupilDetails PDetails
    join Assignment.dbo.TuitionFees Fees
    ON PDetails.Pupil_ID = Fees.Pupil_ID
    WHERE FeeDueDate < dateadd(WEEK, -3, getdate());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Delete using INNER JOIN with SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this query:-

```
CREATE PROC spAreFeesOverDue 
   AS
  BEGIN 
       DELETE  
       FROM Assignment.dbo.PupilDetails PDetails
       join Assignment.dbo.TuitionFees Fees
       ON PDetails.Pupil_ID = Fees.Pupil_ID
      WHERE FeeDueDate < dateadd(WEEK, -3, getdate())
   END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the table you are deleting from.  For instance:

```
DELETE Fees
    FROM Assignment.dbo.PupilDetails PDetails JOIN
         Assignment.dbo.TuitionFees Fees
         ON PDetails.Pupil_ID = Fees.Pupil_ID
    WHERE FeeDueDate < dateadd(WEEK, -3, getdate());
```