# Delete using Inner Joins

Tags: mysql, sql-server, inner-join, sql-delete

So I have this correlated subquery, and I was reading that this is not the most efficient way to go about this. Hence, I want to convert this query to an INNER JOIN query.

```
DELETE FROM tableA
WHERE EXISTS (
           SELECT fieldA
           FROM tableB
           WHERE tableB.fieldA= tableA.fieldA)
```

I tried something like this:

```
DELETE a 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
ON a.fieldA = b.fieldA
```

Which resulted in an `Error while executing SQL query on database 'DB': near "a": syntax error`

All of my search results on here yielded approximately the same query (similar to what I have tried)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server

Comment: Mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: @Jens both please

Comment: What you posted should work perfectly in sql server.

Comment: @SeanLange Maybe that error came from MySQL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am guessing it must have but the OP states they want code for both. What they posted will work in sql server.

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah but if there is a common solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted works fine for `SQL Server`;  for `MySQL` below should do the job

```
DELETE tableA
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableB.fieldA = tableA.fieldA;
```

Comment: @rahul Do you think it's make any effect?? Even though with alias also works fine.