# How to Delete a Record from Multiple Gridviews in SQL Server(VB.NET)?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to Delete data from two gridviews(Using Foreign Key) when i click a button!..This is What I've tried and gives me an error "Incorrect Syntax near "INNER""..Help Me figure this out..

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(Byval.....
Dim command as new SqlCommand("Delete From Students Inner Join Classes ON Students.StudentID=Classes.StudentID Where Students.StudentID='" & Registered.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value & "'",connection)
```

Comment: Your sql syntax is wrong, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server

Comment: i tried that link..but couldn't find a solution...i mean none of those work

Comment: im trying to delete from two tables and also from two DataGridViews

Comment: Improve your question by providing more info. The less effort you put in your question, the less effort you will get in a response. Which tables are you trying to delete from? Are you using data binding for your data grid views? provide the code that binds data to the datagrid view. Try to provide a [mcve]

Comment: That "INNER..." and remaining exception makes sense here since what if there are other dependent tables on either Students/Classes that we don't know? Post relevant details for quick understanding of problem as @Tewr already suggested.

Comment: This is the code

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(Byval.....
Dim command as new SqlCommand("Delete From Students Inner Join Classes ON Students.StudentID=Classes.StudentID Where Students.StudentID='" & Registered.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value & "'",connection)

Comment: If Registered.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Registered.Rows.Remove(Registered.CurrentRow)
     End If
        connection.Open()
        delcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close() If Registered.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Registered.Rows.Remove(Registered.CurrentRow)
        End If
        connection.Open()
        delcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()

Comment: Sorry for not-spacing