# Query for DELETE with INNER JOIN (on a linked server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, linked-server

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16481475/1008588) answer I am trying to make a `DELETE` from a `JOIN`. The query works if both of the tables are on the same server, but now I have two server:

- `TableA` is on `DatabaseA` that is on `ServerA` SQL Server 9.0.4060
- `TableB` is on `DatabaseB` that is on `ServerB` SQL Server 12.0.2000

`ServerA` is a linked server on `ServerB`.

I have the following **TableA** (on `ServerA`)

```
+---------+-----------+------+
|  Name   |  Surname  | Side |
+---------+-----------+------+
| Anakyn  | Skywalker | Bad  |
| Luke    | Skywaler  | Good |
| Obi Wan | Kenobi    | Good |
| Anakyn  | Skywalker | Good |
| Qui gon | Jinn      | Good |
| Darth   | Maul      | Bad  |
+---------+-----------+------+
```

and the following **TableB** (on `ServerB`)

```
+----------+------+
| Surname  | Side |
+----------+------+
| Skywaler | Good |
| Maul     | Bad  |
+----------+------+
```

If I execute this query

```
DELETE A
FROM [ServerA].[DatabaseA].[dbo].[TableA] A
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableB] B
ON A.[Surname]=B.[Surname] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
AND A.[Side]=B.[Side] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

the system gives me an error

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "ServerB" returned
>   message "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each
>   OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.". Msg 7202, Level
>   11, State 2, Line 16 Could not find server 'ServerB' in sys.servers.
>   Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary,
>   execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to
>   sys.servers.

Additional consideration:

- The query `select * from sys.servers where is_linked = 1` executed on ServerB.DatabaseB show me that ServerA is a linked server;
- If replace `DELETE A` with `SELECT A.*` the query show me the correct results that I would like to delete;
- I have checked the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and every columns of the join have `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation;
- From [ServerB] I can delete rows of [ServerA].[DatabaseA].[TableA] if I use a `DELETE` without the `JOIN`.

Anybody have any help for me?

Comment: Does this work `;with cte as (select A .* FROM [ServerA].[DatabaseA].[dbo].[TableA] A
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableB] B
ON A.[Surname]=B.[Surname] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
AND A.[Surname]=B.[Surname] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)select * from cte `

Comment: I think you have simplified to much it is hard to tell what is going on. The error message says ServerB but there is in ServerB in your code. And not sure why you are checking Surname twice. :)

Comment: @TheGameiswar Yes, the query works (and shows me the rows I want to delete)

Comment: @SeanLange You are right, I corrected the query witk the JOIN on [Surname] and [Side]. I've tryed to simplifier as much as I can to make it easily to understand. I could give a more complicated example if needed.

Comment: @paparazzo I have tryed and it works.

Comment: No need to make it more complicated. :) Since you say you have to run this from ServerB maybe you can use IN instead of a join?