# Exception Incorrect syntax near ','. in sql server

Tags: sql-server

trying to delete data from two tables and getting error `Incorrect syntax near ','.`

```
DELETE tblItem, tblCategory
FROM tblCategory
INNER JOIN tblItem
WHERE tblCategory.category_id = tblItem.fk_category
```

**Update**

[image]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DELETE` can only delete from one table at a time, so you will have to do two separate delete statements, in the correct order:

```
DELETE
FROM tblItem
WHERE fk_category IN (...)
```

and then

```
DELETE
FROM tblCategory
WHERE category_id = (...)
```

First we can try deleting all items belonging to certain target categories.  Then, once those child records have been deleted, we can delete the parent category records.

A better way to handle this is to use something like `ON DELETE CASCADE`, which means that if a parent category in `tblCategory` were to be deleted, SQL Server would automatically propagate that delete to all child item records in `tblItem`.

Comment: deleting data from two tables, not a single

Comment: using `tblCategory.*, tblItem.*`, now giving me error of `Incorrect syntax near '*'.`

Comment: Well that's not the syntax I suggested in my answer.  Did you try my answer?

Comment: I copied and pasted your syntax, still getting `Incorrect syntax near '*'.`

Comment: @MWN I think both these answers were misleading you, because I don't think it's possible to delete from two tables at once in SQL Server.  Nor should you really have a good reason to want to do this.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the associating rows with two operations but I checked on `stackover-flow` that some guys `up-voted` the syntax that you suggest earlier for deleting data from two tables but unfortunately this did not work for me.

Comment: I think you were looking at a MySQL question.  Were you looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server)?  Some of those answers look like MySQL syntax to me.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
   DELETE from 
      FROM tblCategory where category_id  in (select  fk_category from  tblItem  )


   DELETE from 
      FROM tblItem  where fk_category in (select  category_id  from  tblCategory )
```

Comment: deleting data from two tables, not a single

Comment: @MWN sorry check now

Comment: @MWN  excuse me what you are speaking ,initially who posted answer first and my answer is same as tim and you are blaming me ..........

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry  i didnt  saw your answer