# Deleting records with T-SQL efficiently without using IN clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax, subquery

Is there an efficient way to delete records from SQL Server without using the keyword `IN` in the below scenario:

```
-- If Documents were deleted, remove them from your ocean
DELETE FROM IndexHistory 
WHERE DocId IN (SELECT IH.Docid 
                FROM IndexHistory IH 
                LEFT JOIN IndexedLineItems I ON IH.Docid = I.DocId
                WHERE I.Docid IS NULL)
```

If you study this scenario, you have all the records you want to delete from the query inside the parenthesis.

It is documented fact that using 'IN' is inefficient. So one would think that there should be a way to delete these without the 'IN', because all your records are identify-able without using the "IN".

So for example, I am thinking that something like this might be possible, but I don't have the right syntax:

```
DELETE FROM IndexHistory IH 
LEFT JOIN IndexedLineItems I ON IH.Docid = I.DocId
WHERE I.Docid IS NULL
```

I appreciate the answer may still be "no, it's not possible."

If it is not possible, maybe it can be a possible suggestion to improve the language for Microsoft. Before I do that, I thought I would post here to see if I'm missing something.

Comment: Don't you mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server

Comment: Marc, not exactly, but it is related and a good find, and helpful for me to post an additional possible answer (mine is not an inner join, but a left join).  Some of the answers on bottom also seem to be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine...

```
DELETE IH
    FROM IndexHistory IH
    Left JOIN IndexedLineItems LI
      ON IH.Docid = LI.DocId
    WHERE LI.DocId is Null
```

Comment: Many great answers, and tons of good information here.  But this is the most direct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use `not exists`:

```
Delete ih from IndexHistory ih
    where not exists (select 1 from IndexedLineItems ili where ih.Docid = ili.DocId)
```

Comment: you missing a join or something?

Comment: @Kam No, it's a correlated subquery.  The join is `ih.Docid = ili.DocId`.

Comment: Fyi, the reason the "not exists" with a correlated subquery works better is it can leverage indexes as its directly joining the outer table to the inner. With an "in" clause, the optimizer cant make assumption about the results it will operate on, so it has to scan it. That turns out to be a big benefit.

Comment: I got error on this one.     Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'ih'.

Comment: @Kam . . . That was a typo . . . I left out the alias.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer CTEs for readability reason, it can also be changed to use a `SELECT` to see what i'm going to delete. This `NOT EXISTS` might also be more efficient:

```
WITH DeleteData AS
(
  SELECT IH.Docid 
  FROM IndexHistory IH 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM IndexedLineItems I
                    WHERE I.DocId = IH.DocId)
)
DELETE FROM DeleteData
```

You don't need an additional JOIN from this CTE to the table because only one table is selected.

Comment: this seemed to have worked.  i've never seen this before (With...).  I will keep the floor open for now, incase there are additional answers.

Comment: @Kam: it's a [common-table-expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). No matter how complex the CTE itself is, you can always write `SELECT * FROM DeleteData` to see what you will delete. Then it might also be useful to add more columns in the CTE(or simply `SELECT IH.* ...`). Its not necessary to select only the Docid.

Answer (score 1):

In a different thinking, use inner join instead, so you only delete the matches:

```
DELETE FROM IndexHistory IH 
JOIN IndexedLineItems I ON IH.Docid = I.DocId
WHERE I.Docid IS NOT NULL
```