# Deleting With join on code igniter MSSQL return an error

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, inner-join, sql-delete

To delete with join we use this format

```
DELETE t1,t2 FROM t1
        INNER JOIN
    t2 ON t2.ref = t1.id 
WHERE
    t1.id = 1;
```

from [www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/)

Follow the exact way to delete but when I implement in my own version I get error in the comma between two tables to be deleted.

This is what I have:

[image]

Seen in the above image my implementation and the error I get.

Any idea is appreciated

`Update`

Same format [stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server)

Comment: You can't able to delete 2 table from single delete query in MSSQL.

Comment: use apostrophe if you didn't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Delete using INNER JOIN with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server)

Comment: @SurajKumar see update i linked the same exact link its not working

Comment: @guradio You are not following the idea suggested there as I said for join you need to give alias name. Can you post sample data at least 2-4 rows and expected output after delete?

Comment: @guradio You have following MySql post and tagged as Sql server (MSSQL) both are different. Please clarify which is correct?

Comment: @SurajKumar it said `You need to specify what table you are deleting from, here is a version with an alias: ` it didnt say you need alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server allows to `DELETE` only from one table in a `DELETE` statement.

In this case you are trying to delete records from two table in a single `DELETE` statement, which is not allowed.

For your case you can simply write the same query like following.

```
DELETE FROM lngFileId 
WHERE lngId=5

DELETE FROM tbl_FileOrPath
WHERE lngFileId=5
```

For More complex scenarios, you can try like following.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE 
  ( 
     id INT 
  ) 

INSERT INTO @TABLE 
SELECT t1.ID 
FROM   t1       
WHERE  <YOUR_CONDITION>

DELETE T 
FROM   t1 T 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   @TABLE T2 
               WHERE  T2.id = T.id) 

DELETE T 
FROM   t2 T 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   @TABLE T2 
               WHERE  T2.id = T.ref)
```

Another scenario can be when you have a `Foreign Key` Relationship between the table with `ON DELETE CASCADE` enabled. For such cases you need to delete only from the parent table, child table records will automatically gets deleted.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set alias for the table for which you want to delete as shown in below example as `w` is used for `WorkRecord2`. It is required when needed with inner join delete or update statements.

```
DELETE w
FROM WorkRecord2 w
INNER JOIN Employee e
  ON EmployeeRun=EmployeeNo
WHERE Company = '1' AND Date = '2013-05-06'
```

Also only one table delete is allowed. Deleting with more than one table is allowed in MySQL not MSSQL. You can find the live demo [Here](https://rextester.com/NITAHL32850).

Below is the query with sample data.

```
create table WorkRecord2 (EmployeeRun int, empWorkNo varchar(10))
create table Employee (EmployeeNo int, empWorkNo varchar(10), company int, createdDate datetime)

insert into WorkRecord2 Values (1, 'EMW101'),(2, 'EMW102'),(3, 'EMW103'),(4, 'EMW104'),(5, 'EMW105')
insert into Employee values(1, 'EMW101', 1, GETDATE()),(2, 'EMW103', 2, GETDATE())

Select * from WorkRecord2
Select * from Employee

-- This will delete with employeeRun 1 and empWorkNo EMW101
DELETE w
FROM WorkRecord2 w
INNER JOIN Employee e
  ON EmployeeRun=EmployeeNo
WHERE Company = 1 and Cast(createdDate as DATE) = Cast(GETDATE() as DATE)

Select * from WorkRecord2
Select * from Employee
```

Before delete the table data is as shown below.

```
EmployeeRun empWorkNo
---------------------
1           EMW101
2           EMW102
3           EMW103
4           EMW104
5           EMW105
```

After delete with inner join the table data is as shown blow.

```
EmployeeRun empWorkNo
---------------------
2           EMW102
3           EMW103
4           EMW104
5           EMW105
```

Comment: @guradio I have added explanation with sample data to show it is correct answer. You where condition need to check if data is not deleting. Also check whether record is coming in inner join or not because only that record will be deleted which will match in inner join.

Comment: this does not satisfy my OP it will delete one table only how is it the correct answer?

Comment: @guradio Deleting with more than one table is allowed in MySQL not MSSQL.