# SQL query comparing column between 2 found sets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table, we'll call it `BUS` and it has two columns called `DATE` and `TAG`

I want to do two finds, as shown below

**Query 1**

```
select * 
from BUS
where DATE < '2009-03-01'
```

&

**Query 2**

```
select * 
from BUS
where DATE >= '2009-03-01'
```

*I want to compare these two found sets, and delete any rows where the `TAG` from query 1 equals the `TAG` from query 2.*

I tried an INTERSECT but I don't think that's the correct way. I can't wrap my head around this kind of query. Any advice?

Comment: Isn't there a primary key in this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Query.

```
delete
from BUS
where DATE < '2009-03-01' 
and tag in 
(select tag from BUS where DATE >= '2009-03-01')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to your problem:

```
-- SELECT b1.*
DELETE b1
FROM BUS b1
  INNER JOIN BUS b2 ON b1.TAG = b2.TAG
WHERE b1.DATE < '2009-03-01' AND b2.DATE >= '2009-03-01';
```

Before executing the query you can comment out the `DELETE` statement, uncomment the `SELECT` statement and check if those are the rows you want gone.

Similar examples can be seen in the documentation (scroll down a bit) and some other SO questions:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
- [How to Delete using INNER JOIN with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
select tag
from BUS
group by tag
having min(date) < '2009-03-01' and
       max(date) >= '2009-03-01';
```